# Mime type for WOFF fonts?

Tags: embedded-fonts, woff

What mime type should WOFF fonts be served as?

I am serving truetype (ttf) fonts as `font/truetype` and opentype (otf) as `font/opentype`, but I cannot find the correct format for WOFF fonts.

I have tried `font/woff`, `font/webopen`, and `font/webopentype`, but Chrome still complains:

"Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream."

Anybody know?

Comment: So there's no way to stop Chrome complaining?

Comment: Here is the Node.js / Meteor Solution:  npm install mime

Comment: also note the other config which at last fixed my problem in IIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7

Comment: `font/woff` is now the correct MIME type for woff and Chrome doesn't complain.

Answer (score 762, accepted):

***Update from [Keith Shaw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708849/154877) on Jun 22, 2017:***

> As of February 2017, [RFC8081](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8081#section-4.4.5) is the proposed standard. It defines a top-level media type for fonts, therefore the standard media type for WOFF and WOFF2 are as follows:
>
> `font/woff`
>
> `font/woff2`

---

In January 2011 [it was announced](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70283#c3) that in the meantime Chromium will recognize

`application/x-font-woff`

as the mime-type for WOFF. I know this change is now in Chrome beta and if not in stable yet, it shouldn't be too far away.

Comment: as of Chromium 18.0, 2012/08/30, need to use application/x-font-woff

Comment: As cc young said, in order to get rid of the Chrome warning "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/font-woff" you need to use "application/x-font-woff"

Comment: Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 seems to still reply with the "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred..." if you use application/font-woff. Seems still need to use "application/x-font-woff" for now.

Comment: Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m does not show the warning for me with application/font-woff

Comment: I see the warning on `24.0.1312.57`, filed a Chromium bug.

Comment: I'm still seeing the warning on `27.0.1423.0`. Do you have a link to the bug report @sandstrom ?

Comment: According to the following Webkit commit, `font/woff` and `application/x-font-woff` will be removed in favor of `application/font-woff`. Also, the warning has been downgraded to a log message.

http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/144763/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/NetworkManager.js

Comment: I added AddType application/x-font-woff woff to my Apache httpd.conf file which fixes the error in Chrome browser but in Safari, I am now getting this error, "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff."

Comment: In addition to Jorrit Schippers comment, Webkit commit was updated after the MIME type was officially registered with IANA as based on the W3C Recommendation, as indicated here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/font-woff so the warning is obsolete now, and this root answer should be updated.

Comment: What about the new `.woff2`?

Comment: update: I just had to set to font/woff on our IIS server to prevent 404s (which in turn broke some really brittle font-loader code) so I think this is now an ex-problem.

Comment: Marcel's answer is not the correct answer anymore. Keith Shaw's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708849/1560865 is the correct one as ow now (since February 2017).

Answer (score 148):

For me, the next has beeen working in an .htaccess file.

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
```

Comment: I can't believe more people haven't found this helpful. This is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: At the time of asking this question 'font/woff' did *not* work. Can anyone confirm that it now does?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. In rails, you need to add the following line to your initializer:

    Mime::Type.register "font/woff", :woff

Comment: In IIS Express, you can add a **mimeMap** element to web.config under configuration/system.webServer/staticContent: `<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />`

Comment: Worked fine when I changed the MIME types in IIS as well. Thanks!

Comment: as of Chrome 18, stopped working.  now application/x-font-woff seems to work.

Comment: Which on is correct solution? this or second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415640/correct-apache-addtype-directives-for-font-mime-types

Comment: For the record, Google Fonts uses `font/woff` and `font/woff2`.

Answer (score 56):

It will be `application/font-woff`.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b (W3C Candidate Recommendation 04 August 2011)

and http://www.w3.org/2002/06/registering-mediatype.html

**From Mozilla css font-face notes**

> In Gecko, web fonts are subject to the same domain restriction (font files must be on the same domain as the page using them), unless HTTP access controls are used to relax this restriction.
>   Note: Because there are no defined MIME types for TrueType, OpenType, and WOFF fonts, the MIME type of the file specified is not considered.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face#Notes

Comment: But as pointed by Marcel after, Chromium will recognize application/x-font-woff as per RFC 2048 until application/font-woff is accepted.

Comment: The WOFF spec is now a recommendation and will not change from application/font-woff http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b

Answer (score 31):

Reference for adding font mime types to .NET/IIS

**via web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
     <!-- remove first in case they are defined in IIS already, which would cause a runtime error -->
     <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
     <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

**via IIS Manager**

[image: screenshot of adding woff mime types to IIS]

Answer (score 25):

**NGINX SOLUTION**

file

```
/etc/nginx/mime.types
```

or

```
/usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types
```

add

```
font/ttf                      ttf;
font/opentype                 otf;
font/woff                     woff;
font/woff2                    woff2;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;
```

remove

```
application/octet-stream        eot;
```

**REFERENCES**

RFC @02.2017

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8081#page-15

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Thanks to Mike Fulcher

http://drawingablank.me/blog/font-mime-types-in-nginx.html

Answer (score 23):

As of February 2017, [RFC8081](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8081) is the proposed standard. It defines a top-level media type for fonts, therefore the standard media type for WOFF and WOFF2 are as follows:

```
font/woff
font/woff2
```

Answer (score 11):

*Note: This answer was correct at it's time but became outdated in 2017 when [RFC 8081](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8081) was released*

There is no `font` MIME type! Thus, `font/xxx` is ALWAYS wrong.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja this answer is incomplete, but not wrong. The only thing that changed between this answer and your comment is `application/font-woff` was added to the standard, replacing such things as `application/x-font-woff` (actual software updating in practice is another matter). Nothing has made madey-uppey content-types of the form `font/xxx` valid.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your .htaccess

```
AddType font/woff woff
```

good luck

Answer (score 5):

Thing that did it for me was to add this to my mime_types.rb initializer:

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES['.woff'] = 'font/woff'
```

**and** wipe out the cache

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

before restarting the server.

Source: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/366#issuecomment-9085509

Answer (score 4):

**@Nico**,

Currently there is no defined standard for the woff font mime type.  I use a font delivery cdn service and it uses font/woff and I get the same warning in chrome.

Reference: [The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/)

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

This is a helpful list of mimetypes

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is kind of old but after spending many hours on trying to make the fonts work on my nginx local machine and trying a tons of solutions i finally got the one that worked for me like a charm.

```
location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Inside the parenthesis you can put the extensions of your fonts or generally the files that you want to load. For example i used it for fonts and for images(png,jpg etc etc) as well so don't get confused that this solution applies only for fonts.

Just put it into your nginx config file, restart and i hope it works also for you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone. I saw that on IIS 7 `.ttf` is already a known mime-type. It's configured as:

```
application/octet-stream
```

So I just added that for all the CSS font types (`.oet`, `.svg`, `.ttf`, `.woff`) and IIS started serving them. Chrome dev tools also do not complain about re-interpreting the type.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: 'application/octet-stream' is the web server equivalent of saying "I don't know what this is".

Comment: Yes, I know. But the key point was that it worked whereas many of the more specific options didn't seem to result in the fonts being used over IIS7. My comment was more pragmatic than trying to be the most correct (because that wasn't working).

Answer (score 1):

**For all Solution index.php remove form url and woff file allowed. for write below code in .htaccess file and and make this alternation to your application/config/config.php file:
$config['index_page'] = '';**

**For only Linux hosting server.**
**.htaccess file details**

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

WOFF:

1. Web Open Font Format
2. It  can be compiled with either TrueType or PostScript (CFF) outlines
3. It is currently supported by FireFox 3.6+

Try to add that:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/octet-stream .otf .ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS automatically defined .ttf as application/octet-stream which seems to work fine and fontshop recommends .woff to be defined as application/octet-stream

Answer (score -1):

Mime type might not be your only problem. If the font file is hosted on S3 or other domain, you may additionally have the issue that Firefox will not load fonts from different domains. It's an easy fix with Apache, but in Nginx, I've read that you may need to encode your font files in base-64 and embed them directly in your font css file.