# Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

So I'm trying to prototype a marketing page and I'm using Bootstrap and the new Font Awesome file. The problem is that when I try to use an icon, all that gets rendered on the page is a big square.

Here's how I include the files in the head:

```
<head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <!--[if IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
        <![endif]-->
</head>
```

And here's an example of me trying to use an icon:

```
<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i>
```

But all that gets rendered in a big square. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: Are you importing the font?

Comment: Probably not. I thought you only had to include the `.css` file.

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration step 3

Comment: I'm not using less. Just CSS. I followed the "Easy Bootstrap + Font Awesome Integration"

Comment: The title implies that the problem is specific to Chrome.  Is it loading in other browsers or is the referenced font file turning up a 404?

Comment: are you running any browser plugins? HttpsAnywhere causes font awesome issues for us all the time.

Comment: Can't find step 3 on above link as of Aug 2016...Any redirections??

Comment: Probably you forgot copy webfont folder?

Comment: Issue for me was forgetting the webfont folder. The updated doc link I discovered is https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Answer (score 158, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration) (step 3), you need to modify the supplied CSS file to point to the font location on your site.

Comment: Great answer, just to give some additional info, you can as well place the fonts in the default path provided by the css, just open Font-awesome.css and you will find the following entry: @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1')

Comment: Just for future ASP.NET MVC readers with the same problem: If you have all the folders in the correct place, verify if you added the MIME type on your web.config file as pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files

Comment: If you use the Data URI Scheme with a base64 version of the font (can easily convert online), then you don't have to worry about proper file path and resource hosting.

Comment: **Note**:if you don't want to modify the css, just put css and fonts in same folder, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30098214/2218697)

Comment: It is still useful if using it building some browser extensions, where JS files must be local

Comment: @tutuca: Not everybody can use a CDN.

Comment: @tutuca are you saying you'r using the cdn. but when running it in local host 
the icons just do not render ?

Comment: I did all of this and I cant still resolve the empty square showing box. On local. I cant used CDN.

Comment: Not answerers fault, but modifying the css is not a great process, because if you're integrating these files using npm then they are going to get overwritten each restore.  This is why libs like bootstrap let you supply your own variables file to mix in during compile with the default files so you can provide variables without modifying the package files.

Comment: Updated Hosting documentation by FontAwesome 
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Answer (score 234):

You must have 2 classes, the `fa` class and the class that identifies the desired icon `fa-twitter`, `fa-search`, etc …

```
<!-- Wrong -->
<i class="fa-search"></i>    

<!-- Correct -->
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

#### Bootstrap 5 update

> Note: "The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the `fas` solid style and the `fab` style for brands." – [Terje Solem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares/21815998#comment84931918_21815998)

Comment: This should be the top answer, the CSS provided points to the right location for the font files so long as you dont move them - this was driving me up the wall thank you

Comment: Note: "The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands."

Comment: This fixed it for me! I am using Angular (5 I think) along with primeng and it seems, that font-awesome already worked for e.g. MenuItem-definitions inside xx.component.ts (the icons rendered correctly). However: when adding something to xx.component.html (e.g. p-button with an icon), one **has to** add **fa** class **and** fa-<whatever icon>!

Comment: @TerjeSolem the information you gave is very important. It solved my problem. as i was using older version but was using "fas" thanks

Comment: The CSS classes are an absolute mess, and seem designed to cause problems for non-premium users. Even the documentation is incorrect, some of the icons tell you to use e.g. `fa-solid fa-comment` in v5, but the icon only loads using `fa fa-solid fa-comment` which according to their site is deprecated.

Answer (score 81):

Use this

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I had similar issue with Amazon Cloudfront CDN but it got resolved after I started loading it from maxcdn

Comment: this assumes you wish to use font-awesome's CDN.  For a commercial production environment I would not do this.

Comment: @JayEdwards why not?

Comment: Because you're pulling from a resource that is not managed by you and is subject to whatever fate throws at it (e.g. scheduled server maintenance by font-awesome that you have no control over at times that are inconvenient for the region(s) in which you're hosting your service); to say nothing of the fact that you're relying on something that may be hosted nowhere near your own service, thereby adding needless traffic to your page load.  Subject to your use-case I would use something webpack driven to locally retrieve the icons you need.  E.g. In VueJS, I use Vue-Awesome.

Comment: this wont work as so many of my project now running to problem because of this CDN is not reachable 
best to do it host in your server.

Answer (score 69):

**Check to ensure that you haven't inadvertently changed the font family** on the icon. If you have changed the .fa item's font family from: FontAwesome the icon will not show. It's always something silly and small.

Comment: Yep. Silly and small. This - changing the font for something else and affecting fontawesome icons - happened to me so many times that it's becoming stupid.

Comment: Yes - this line was to blame (to be more specific, the !important rule) : * { font-family: 'Source Sans Pro' !important}

Comment: Thank you so much! I was importing this and that only to find the issue with font-family override.

Comment: Be careful of another silly mistake: I was using the FREE version of font-awesome and was trying e.g. to use fa-binoculars with fa-regular, which only works for the PRO version, while fa-binoculars with fa-solid works with the FREE version, which made me think that I didn't install the fonts correctly. This answer reminded me of sanity-checks.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using LESS or SASS, open the font-awesome.less/sass file and edit the path variable `@fa-font-path: "../font";` which points to the actual fonts:

```
@fa-font-path: "../font";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Same with CSS, except you edit the path in the @font-face declaration block:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('your/path/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('your/path/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('your/path/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('your/path/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only import certain icons instead of all of them? I'd only like to compile my css file to a few icons.

Comment: `@fa-font-path: "../fonts";` worked for me. (Notice the missing `s` added)

Answer (score 22):

Open your font-awesome.css
theres code like :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

you must have folder like :

```
font awesome -> css
             -> fonts
```

or the easiest way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 18):

You must have 2 classes, the `fas` class and the `fa-*` class. See [Basic Use](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) in the docs:

> The `fa` prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the `fas` solid style and the `fab` style for brands.

```
// Correct (version >= 5)
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>    

// Wrong (version < 5)
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Comment: Didn't realise this - from v5 they now require a `fab` or `fas` class instead of the `fa` class.

Answer (score 15):

I am using `Font Awesome 4.3.0` just linking from **maxcdn works** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24923640/2218697),

But **to host in your server** putting fonts and CSS in same folder worked for me, like this

[image]

Then just link the CSS:

```
<link href="~/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the version 5.* or greater, then you have to use the

> all.css 
>   or
>   all.min.css

Including the fontawesome.css does not work as it has no reference to the **webfonts** folder and there is no reference to the @font-face or font-family

You can inspect this by searching the code for the font-family property in fontawesome.css or fontawesome.min.css

Comment: this one was the perfect solution for me - too bad the answer is so far below, I didn't see it and had to figure it out by myself

Comment: THANK YOU! The problem was I only imported fontawesome.css for version 5. Version 4 works ok with fontawesome.css.

Comment: Correct answer for me with Blazor!

Answer (score 14):

I tried to solve the same problem with a few previous solutions, but they didn't work in my situation.
Finally, I added these 2 lines in HEAD and it worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue and went through each step carefully...even though I've been using FA for ages...and then I realized I had this line in my mail css file:

```
* {
font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

Silly mistake, but this could tip off someone in future!

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue!

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue. The problem was I had a font-family CSS style with !important overriding the fontawesome font.

Comment: I had the same issue with * {
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
}

Answer (score 6):

In case you are working with **Maven** and **Apache Wicket** also check for the following in order to try to resolve the issue with Font-Awesome and icons not being loaded:

If you have placed your files for example in the following file structure

```
/src
 /main
  /java
   /your
    /package
     /css
      font-awesome.css
     /font
      fontawesome-webfont.eot
      fontawesome-webfont.svg
      fontawesome-webfont.svgz
      fontawesome-webfont.ttf
      fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

**Check 1)** Are you correctly using a Package Resource Guard in order to allow to load the font files correctly?

Example from your class which extends WebApplication:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();   
    get().getResourceSettings().setPackageResourceGuard(new PackageResourceGuard());

}
```

**Check 2)** After you have made sure that all fonts are correctly transferred to the Web Browser, check for what has been actually transferred to the Web Browser, i.e., did the integrity of the font files change? Compare the files in your source directory and the files transferred to the Web Browser using, e.g., the Web Developer Toolbar of Firefox and DiffDog (for file comparison).

In particular if you are using Maven be aware of resource filtering. Do not filter the folder where your /font files are contained - otherwise they will be corrupted.

Example from your pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>Your project</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

In the example above we do not filter the folder src/main/java, where the css and font files are contained.

For further information on the filtering of binary data please also see the documentation:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

In particular the documentation warns: "*Warning:* Do not filter files with
binary content like images! This will most likely result in corrupt output.
If you have both text files and binary files as resources, you need to
declare two mutually exclusive resource sets. The first resource set
defines the files to be filtered and the other resource set defines the
files to copy unaltered..."

Answer (score 6):

As of Dec 2018, I find it easier to use the stable version 4.7.0 hosted on bootstrapcdn instead of the [font-awesome 5.x.x cdn on their website](https://fontawesome.com/start) -- since every time they upgrade minor versions the previous version WILL break.

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Icons are the same:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

Answer (score 5):

`font-weight: 900;`

I had a different issue with Font Awesome 5.
Default font-weight should be 900 for FontAwesome icons but I overwrote it to 400 for span and i tags.
It just worked, when I corrected it.

Here is the issue reference in their Github page, https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11946

Answer (score 4):

This should be much simpler in the new version 3.0. Easiest is to point to the Bootstrap CDN: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=01042013155511#tab_fontawesome

Answer (score 4):

If your server is IIS, be sure to add the correct MIME to serve .woff file extension.
The correct MIME is `application/octet-stream`

Comment: If you are using IIS 7, you can follow the procedure here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You must return the header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to ***** for your fonts files

Comment: Exactly! Using third party providers to serve your font awesome files does not solve your problem, you just passing it to others to be solved.

Answer (score 3):

After struggling for finding a solution and NOT finding the official documentation helpful, this solved the issue for me:

1. Download the Fontawesome.zip. I'm using version 5.10.2 and i got it from here https://fontawesome.com/download
2. Inside the zip file there are several folders.You only need css and webfonts folders
   [image]
3. Create 2 folders in your web projects, and name them css and webfonts.
   [image]

These names are mandatory. Now copy the content of css and webfonts from the zip into the corresponding folders in your project. And that's all!

And reference like so in your html

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/brands.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/solid.min.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with font awesome 5 downloaded with yarn,
I made added the min.css file **ALONG** with the all.js file.

Hope this helps someone someone

```
<link  rel="stylesheet"   href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<script src="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible that your font path is not correct so that css not able to load the font and render the icons so you need to provide the stranded path of attached fonts.

```
@font-face { 
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro" ></i>` you have not defined fa classes

Answer (score 2):

Starting in version 5, if you downloaded the package from this site:

https://fontawesome.com/download

The fonts are in the all.css and all.min.css file.

This is what your reference would look like using the latest version now (replace with your folder):

```
<link href="/MyProject/Content/fontawesome-free-5.10.1-web/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

MUST WORK THIS WAY

1. make sure you have the fontawesome cdn linked in the top of your page
   [fontawesome cdn](http://link%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css%22)
2. make sure the .fa class has not been given another font-family property. Usually this happens when we give all the tags in our page a style. like this

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

instead use this

```css
*:not(.fa){
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

3. make sure you typed in the exact class name give in the fontawesome website. copy and paste to make sure.

If you are using Cloudflare CDN you can use the link tag below to use font awesome in your page

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed from 3.2.1 to 4.0.1 and the folder was font and now is called fonts.

```
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');

src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.1');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Official Font Awesome SASS Ruby Gem](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) and fixed the error by adding the below line to my application.css.scss

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
```

Explanation:

> The font-awesome-sprockets file includes the sprockets assest helper Sass functions used for finding the proper path to the font file.

Answer (score 1):

if your using sass and have imported in your main.scss

`@import '../vendor/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';`

The error may come from the font-awesome.scss file that is looking for the font files in it's relative path.

So **remember** to override the $fa-font-path variable:

`$fa-font-path:  "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts" !default;`

like this there is no need to add the cdn in your index.html

Answer (score 1):

Double check the fontawesome-all.css file - at the very bottom there will be a path to the webfonts folder. Mine had "../webfonts" format in it, which meant that the css file would be looking 1 level up from where it is. As all of my css files were in css folder and I added the fonts to the same folder, this was not working.

Just move your fonts folder up a level and all should be well :)

Tested with Font Awesome 5.0

Comment: This should be the preferred answer since it answers the question directly without linking to outdated documentation. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

Use with the upper class

```
<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The /css/all.css file contains the core styling plus all of the icon styles that you’ll need when using Font Awesome. The /webfonts folder contains all of the typeface files that the above CSS references and depends on.

Copy the entire /webfonts folder and the /css/all.css into your project’s static assets directory (or where ever you prefer to keep front end assets or vendor stuff).

Add a reference to the copied /css/all.css file into the  of each template or page that you want to use Font Awesome on.

Just Visit - https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself
You will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the (free) Font Awesome 5 version, there's this tiny detail which was hard to figure out for me and I didn't pay attention to it:

```
Style   Availability    Style Prefix    Example Rendering
Solid   Free            fas             <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
Brands  Free            fab             <i class="fab fa-font-awesome"></i>
```

(extracted from the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use))

With this cited, **brand** icons such as `fa-twitter` or `fa-react` need to be used with class **`fab`** while **all other** (free) icons need to be used with class **`fas`**. That's easy to oversee.

Comment: Yep, that was it. The `fa` prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the `fas` solid style and the `fab` style for brands.

Answer (score 1):

After 5+ hours of struggling I found what was causing the problem for me.

1. Using FontAwesome 5 you should be using fa**s** (notice the "s" at the end):

```html
<i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
```

2. I was using "regular" font, which apparently is paid in this version - I switched to "solid" and it all started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute instead of relative paths solved it for me. I was using relative paths (see first example below) and that didn't work. I checked via console and found the server was returning a 404, files not found.

**Relative path caused a 404:**

```
@font-face { 
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3");
}
```

**Absolute path solved it cross browser:**

```
@font-face { 
font-family: "FontAwesome";
src: url("http://www.mysite.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3");
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you have to, but it works for me. Ofcourse, you should repeat this for all the font formats in the font-awesome.css file.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me because I had `Allow from none` directive for the root directory in my apache config. Here's how I got it to work...

My directory structure:

```
root/
root/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
root/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.*
root/dir1/index.html
```

where my index.html has:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I chose to continue to disallow access to my root and instead added another directory entry in my apache config for root/font-awesome/

```
<Directory "/path/root/font-awesome/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with adding the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

inside a

```
<!-- build:css assets/styles/main.css -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

tag

I fixed it by placing it outside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue for me (on my Windows 7 machine) was decrypting my project directory. It's crazy how many visual and functional glitches originally arise from that when testing your website. Just get to a command prompt and run:

```
attrib -R %PROJECT_PATH%\*.* /S
cipher /a /d /s:%PROJECT_PATH%
```

...where %PROJECT_PATH% is the full pathname to the directory where your code is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Now in fontawesome 5 you can deliver a cached version of JS over Https.

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

More info on https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js

Answer (score 0):

I tried a number of the suggestions above without success.

I use the NuGeT packages.
The are (*for some reason*) multiple named version (*font-awesome, fontawesome, font.awesome, etc.*)

For what it's worth:
I removed all the version installed and then only installed the latest version of **font.awesome**. **font.awesome** just worked without the need to tweak or configure anything.

I assume there are a number of things are missing from the other named versions.

Comment: The following is needed in the header:

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/fontawesome-all.min.css" />

Answer (score 0):

So many answers so I add my working for me (Change name if you dont use PRO):
In _typography.less

```
//
//  Common
//  _____________________________________________

& when (@media-common = true) {
  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__fontawsomeregular,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/webfonts/fa-regular-400',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal
  );
  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__fontawsomelight,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/webfonts/fa-light-300',
    @font-weight: 300,
    @font-style: normal
   );
  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__fontawsomebrands,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/webfonts/fa-brands-400',
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
  );
  .lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__fontawsomesolid,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/webfonts/fa-solid-900',
    @font-weight: 900,
    @font-style: normal
  );
}
```

In _theme.less

```
@import '../includes/fontawesome/fontawesome.less';
@fa-font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/webfonts';

//  Fonts
@font-family-name__fontawsomeregular: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
@font-family-name__fontawsomelight: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
@font-family-name__fontawsomebrands: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
@font-family-name__fontawsomesolid: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
```

and example of usage:

```
 .my-newclass:before{
     content: '\f002';
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
     font-family:  @font-family-name__fontawsomelight;
     font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
@import 'https://****.net/*********/font-awesome.min.css';
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('https://****.net/*********/FontAwesome.otf');
    src: url('https://****.net/*********/FontAwesome.otf?#iefix')
}
```

This to top of your css, download and link the css and font correctly, the problem is due to FontAwesome not loading correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you installed `font-awesome` via package manager ([yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/font-awesome) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome)) then, please be aware which version was installed.  Alternatively, if you've already installed `font-awesome` long time ago then, check what version was installed.

In essence, versions installed via package managers might be behind version that is shown on https://fontawesome.com/ website. Thus, as it is today (21.06.2019) package manager will install **v4.7.0** as the latest version but, website will point to documentation that refers to **v5.***.

Solution, visit the website that documents icons for `v4.7.0` https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0, copy appropriate icon e.g. `<i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and incorporate it into your html. More context can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-why/56702714#56702714).

Answer (score 0):

If the MIME TYPE is already having the .woff and .woff2 file types and still it's giving HTTP-404 error, check the request filtering. If this is restrictive, add these file types these with allow to serve and it shall work. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just copied

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-tags"></i> //provided by font awesome
```

for an existing front-end template that included some other icons from font awesome, but this did not worked, So by adding 'fas' class and it worked ;

```
<i class="fas fa-solid fa-tags"></i> //working
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution today which was to:

1. Download the entire project from their Github [page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome)
2. Then follow the rest of the steps on their [page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) under the Default CSS section about moving the directory into your project and adding the link in the HEAD section of an .html file

The problem with their documentation is that they do not specify a link to where you should get a copy of the entire font-awesome project to put into your project.