# Font Awesome icons are not working, I have included all required files

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome icons of version *4.1.0* on my website but they are not working, I have referenced them in the `head` of my page.

I have tried using two methods.

1. `<a class="btn-cta-freequote" href="#">Get a FREE Quote <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>`
2. `<li><a href="index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></span>Home</a></li>`

Here is the CDN link I am using:
`<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Here is the full HTML:

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Retrica</title>
        <link src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="style/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="style/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header class="top-header">
            <div class="container"><!-- Start Container -->
                <div class="row"><!-- Start Row -->
                    <div class="span3"><!-- Start Span3 -->
                        <div class="logo"><img src="img/Retrica.@2x.png" alt="" width="67px" height="13,5px"></div>
                    </div><!-- End Span3 -->
                    <div class="span9"><!-- Start Span9 -->
                        <nav class="main-nav">  <!-- Start Nav -->
                        
                            <a class="btn-cta-freequote" href="#">Get a FREE Quote <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="nav-ul"> <!-- Start Unordered List -->
                                <li><a href="index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></span>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-mobile-phone fa-2x"></span> Contact Us</a></li>
                                
                            </ul> <!-- End Unordered List -->
                        </nav><!-- End Nav -->
                    </div><!-- End Span9 -->
                </div><!-- End Row -->
            </div><!-- End Container -->
        </header>
        
        <section>

            <a href="#" class="btncta">Register Now</a>
        </section>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: Works fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF7x4/

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares

Comment: Please try another version of font-awesome. For example, some icons weren't showing up for me on the version 4.3.0 but they did appear on   4.7.0.

Comment: I was able to get Font Awesome to work by using the all.min.css file.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Under your reference, you have this:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Specifically, the `href=` part.

However, under your full html is this:

```
<link src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Have you tried replacing `src=` with `href=` in your full html to become this?

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Works for me: http://codepen.io/TheNathanG/pen/xbyFg

Comment: **Note**: some times you might see empty boxes, then double check that you  have css and fonts file in same folder check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30098214/2218697), hope helps someone.

Comment: Another issue is that the fontawesome css cannot find the font files which are required. Make sure they are in a folder called webfonts at the root of the project.  Look in the browser console for any message about a font not being found, and look to see where it is trying to download it from and make sure your fonts are in that location.

Answer (score 166):

For seekers of missing font-awesome icons, I have collected a few ideas:

- Assure you use a correct link to the CDN, such as:

  ```
  <link 
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" 
    rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css'>
  ```
- If your page uses HTTPS, do you link to the font-awesome CSS using HTTPS (replace `http://` with `https://` in the link above).
- Double check that you don't have AdBlock Plus or uBlock enabled. They might be blocking some of the icons.
- Reset your browsers cache. (On Chrome do a looong click on the reload button and select Hard Cache Reset)
- Assure that the `<span>` or `<i>` element you use, uses the `FontAwesome` font family. For example, it must not just

  ```
  <i class="fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
  ```

  but

  ```
  <i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
  ```

  It won't work if you have something as the following in your CSS:

  ```
  * {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif !important;   
  }
  ```
- If you are using IE8, are you using a HTML5 Shim?
- If this doesn't work, there are further [Troubleshooting Ideas](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting) on the Font Awesome Wiki.

Comment: I will add : Check your .htaccess is not blocking ttf, svg, eot, or woff extensions

Comment: I missed to add the single `fa` as class name first. Thanks. Perfect answer for finding the problem step by step.

Comment: For me it was something else setting the font-family

Comment: For me I had "font-weight: 500" (to make it consistent with theme I was using). I had to set it to "font-weight: bold"

Comment: Check it is not a browser specific problem. Failed in Firefox V67.
Worked as a private page in Firefox Developers edition (V67). Cleared cache for today and then it worked in Firefox (v67) normally.
Also worked fine in Chrome.

Comment: for me it was a broken icon - I was using "fas" as per the font awesome site, changed it to "fa" and it worked great. Maybe because I was running version 4.5.0

Comment: For me I had : font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif !important;   I disabled this and it worked immediatly. Thanks man :)

Comment: If you're using next.js you need to follow these steps for the CSS to be set up correctly: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/use-with#next-js

Comment: Thanks - adding 'fa' sorted it for me, weird that this isn't in the Font Awesome icon code by default!

Answer (score 52):

At first I couldn't get this to work with *Font Awesome 5*:

```
<i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
```

That's why I came here, being unfamiliar with font awesome. So when I looked further I noticed that my issue was merely an issue with the version.

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_intro.asp) helped me out in this case.

> New in Font Awesome 5 is the `fas` prefix, Font Awesome 4 uses `fa`.
>
> The s in `fas` stands for *solid*, and some icons also have a
>   *regular* mode, specified by using the prefix `far`.

I already noticed the different files in the FontAwesome css folder, like:

- all.min.css
- brands.min.css
- fontawesome.min.css
- regular.min.css
- solid.min.css

And that's when I realized my mistake. All I had to do was include the appropriate css to the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Font-Awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Font-Awesome/css/regular.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Font-Awesome/css/solid.min.css">
```

And then reference the correct item:

```
<i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
```

This setup works for me. Though not all items have equivalents in each type. This will not work:

```
<i class="far fa-sort-down"></i>
```

As a side note, when you don't want to reference all seperate files then this will suffice:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Font-Awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/Font-Awesome/css/all.min.css">
```

Comment: In addition, the [cheatsheet](https://origin.fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) shows which items are available for each icon type.

Comment: I had to include font-awesome.min.css fwiw. This post helped me though.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/magnifying-glass-dollar?s=solid does not use fas

Answer (score 17):

I got the similar problem, Shows icons in square, tried as per the instructions specified here : https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Resolved by using this reference in head section of html page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
```

Answer (score 14):

Mine was not working because I wanted an icon which was not released in the FA version I was using.

This answers why some icons shows but others no.

Pretty obvious but I guess some people still fall for this. Like me.

Comment: Or you are trying to use an older font that no longer exists in the version you are using.  This one, for example, is just called times-circle not times-circle-o which is the old name:  https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/times-circle-o

Answer (score 12):

Just adding some more info to the above answers in regards with update on fontawesome,

If you use font awesome 5,

a. just copy-to-paste the below HTML,

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Note:** Better to include all your scripts within the `<body> {YOUR_SCRIPT_HERE}</body>` and just before  (YOUR_CLOSING_BODY)

b. And for example,

```
<li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/{USER}" class="social-icons"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: How about serving the css locally instead of linking to the fa website?

Answer (score 7):

You must use https for maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com. Only https on maxcdn support CORS

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 6):

## Notes

This answer is created when the latest version of [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/) is **v5.*** but [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/font-awesome) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) version points to **v4.*** (21.06.2019). In other words, **versions installed via package managers is behind latest release !**

If you installed `font-awesome` via package manager ([yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/font-awesome) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome)) then, please be aware which version was installed.  Alternatively, if you've already installed `font-awesome` long time ago then, check what version was installed.

**Installing font-awesome as new dependency:**

```sh
$ yarn add font-awesome
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ font-awesome@4.7.0
info All dependencies
└─ font-awesome@4.7.0
Done in 3.32s.
```

**Checking what version of font-awesome is already installed:**

```sh
$ yarn list font-awesome
yarn list v1.16.0
warning Filtering by arguments is deprecated. Please use the pattern option instead.
└─ font-awesome@4.7.0
Done in 0.79s.
```

## Problem

After you installed `font-awesome` dependency, you incorporate one of these two source files `font-awesome.css` or `font-awesome.min.css` (founded in `node_modules/font-awesome/css/`) into **header** of your webpage e.g.

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
```

Next, you visit https://fontawesome.com/. You select free icons and you search for **sign-in** icon (as an example). You copy the icon e.g. `<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>`, you paste it into your html and, icon is not shown, or is display as square or rectangle !

## Solution

In essence, versions installed via package managers is behind version that is shown on https://fontawesome.com/ website. As you can see we installed `font-awesome v4.7.0` but, website shows documentation for `font-awesome v5.*`. Solution, visit the website that documents icons for `v4.7.0` https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0, copy appropriate icon e.g. `<i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>` and incorporate it into your html.

Comment: They have released a new package [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) that has the latest version. It's also compatible with less and sass \o/

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by putting the Fonts directory at the same level as my CSS files.

Answer (score 5):

For version 5:

If you downloaded the free package from this site:

https://fontawesome.com/download

The fonts are in the **all.css** and **all.min.css** file.

So your reference will look something like this:

```
<link href="/MyProject/Content/fontawesome-free-5.10.1-web/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The fontawesome.css file does not include the font reference.

Answer (score 4):

To whoever may be checking this out in 2018. I am using font awesome 4.7.0 and I got this issue solved by simply taking out the `s` in `fas` as seen in the code `<i class="fa fa-[icon-name]"></i>`. This was originally `<i class="fas fa-[icon-name]"></i>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Plus I am running the node.js server.

Comment: _New in Font Awesome 5 is the fas prefix, Font Awesome 4 uses fa._ From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_intro.asp)

Answer (score 2):

adding this worked for me:

```
<link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[take a look](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGaeGr)

so full example is:

```html
<link href="https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="btn-cta-freequote" href="#">Compute <i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define custom CSS you must set `font-weight: 900;` for some newer Font Awesome library (from version 5). Not setting this font-weight it may show squares.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using blogger hosting, use this url stylesheet css:

```
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below two links keep in header tag.

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Getting the Icons from the below link :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<a class="icon fa-car" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;" href="http://viettelquangbinh.com"></a>
```

and style after:

```
.icon::before {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: .5em;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size: inherit;
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the CDN link that you had posted i suppose is why it wasnt showing correctly, you can use this one below, it works perfectly for me.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the rel and type, as in `rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'`, in the link to the Awesomefont CSS file.
Without these the file wasn't loading correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in .htaccess file in the directory of awesome font

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/woff .woff
AddType font/woff .woff2
AddType font/otf .svg

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and it's working.

Instead of this

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Use it with HTTPS

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this link:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/brands.min.css" integrity="sha512-AMDXrE+qaoUHsd0DXQJr5dL4m5xmpkGLxXZQik2TvR2VCVKT/XRPQ4e/LTnwl84mCv+eFm92UG6ErWDtGM/Q5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of Angular, just installing the package with npm/yarn is not enough. You also need to import the css file (with `@import "~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";`) in your *styles.scss* .

Answer (score -1):

You need a font importer.| try

```
<style> 
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css););
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

I got mine to work by editing the main font-awesome.css file. It has urls to the src (woff, eot, etc...) I had to change them to the absolute path eg: http://mywebsite.com/font-awesome.woff 
Then it worked!

Comment: I'd rather not recommend this since you're editing an external file. You (or your team) will need to remember this every time they need to update fontawesome.

Answer (score -7):

Change this:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To this:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I believe you need the `http:` otherwise it doesn't know what protocol to use (and uses the wrong one, `file:` for instance, as a result).