# Part of font-awesome icon not displaying

Tags: css, font-awesome

Strangely only a part of my font-awesome icon are displaying... do you have already encountered this problem?

I've checked everything from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-why) but nothing worked.

So just to clarify: there should be a newspaper next to newsletter and a clock next to "Historique".

[image]

They are exactly the same elements :

```
<button value="newsl"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> <em>Recevez la newsletter</em></button>
<button value="favoris"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <em>Mes favoris</em></button>
<button value="historique"><i class="fa fa-history"></i> <em>Historique</em></button>
```

And answer to no specific CSS style.

Where could the problem come from?

**[Here is a link where you can see the problem](http://dev.agencedevoyage.com/)**

From [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting) I assumed it could come from an older version load with the theme template I'm using So I've found older versions and deleted them then load font-awesome from the last CDN possible. No progression anyway.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: please provide your with a demo fiddle!

Comment: @Krish obviously it would work on a fiddle --' Just for you https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/agt6qpy6/

Comment: @Baldráni check with the inspector tool if the icon has font size, it has a color or any other value, it's hard to tell what the problem could be if the fiddle works

Comment: Do you have an actual link showing the issue we could look at..since it works in the JSfiddle?

Comment: Check the code for the typos. Clear cache and run it again !

Comment: @Baldráni, fiddle is okay, then can you provide a link with defected issue?

Comment: @Signo As I've said, they all react to the same css. Since fa-heart is working this is not it

Comment: @Paulie_D I've had a link to the dev server

Comment: Can't see the link to the CDN at the live link.

Comment: @Paulie_D I push it then just a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your font-awesome `css` is not latest, when I imported latest [font-awesome](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) css file in to your screen.css it will working fine.

```css
 @import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
```

```html
<button value="newsl"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> <em>Recevez la newsletter</em></button>
<button value="favoris"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <em>Mes favoris</em></button>
<button value="historique"><i class="fa fa-history"></i> <em>Historique</em></button>
```

Comment: Yeah !! Great one ! So I dont understand why it was not good simply by the head... maybe du to gulpfile ?)

Answer (score 1):

You are using FontAwesome `4.0.3` and fa-history has been added in `4.1` so it is completely not present in your font set.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in .htaccess file in the directory of awesome font

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/woff .woff
AddType font/woff .woff2
AddType font/otf .svg

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```