# font-awsome icon doesn't show up

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have used fontawsome befor but on my new project I have tried all possible ways but the icon doesn't show up.
I have set the font's location manually and I have removed the font's location from the css file and set it manually like this :

```
<style>
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome' !important;src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'),url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url ?>/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

this is the result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6X38.jpg

and this is the firefox inspector result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF0Ay.jpg

What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FontAwesome icons not showing. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-why)

Comment: what is the <?php echo $base_url ?> you are getting and also you are missing semicolon " ; " in php tag

Comment: i think the extensions after the **fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot** were not necessary? they could also be the reason of error. try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an complete example for you : [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGaeGr)

```
 <link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="btn-cta-freequote" href="#">Compute <i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link your header section
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.css"