# fa fa-icons not working with #tag_selector * {_CSS_}

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-awesome, css-specificity

I have an override CSS, in style tag as following,

```css
#MainContent * {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: small !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainContent">
    <div id="head">
        <h3>Some Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="abc" class="def">
        <strong>Social:</strong>
        <a title="LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin">
          <span class="sr-only">LinkedIn Page</span>
          </i>
        </a>

        <a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter">
          <span class="sr-only">Twitter Page</span>
          </i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But with This fa fa-icons doesn't show up.
I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-why) discussion, which says it will not work with

> class *{*CSS*}
>
> Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: what do you have for the abc and def? that code shouldn't affect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to redefine

```
i.fa {
    font-family: FontAwesome!important;
}
```

This should come after your `* {}` definition.

Explanation:

You force assign font Lucida to all elements, but font awesome needs `font-family: FontAwesome`.

Also a same style which comes after another one could overwrite it, if they have the same importance.

Comment: Oh man, thanks, I had the same problem and almost decided not to use it anymore because I couldn't see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set an excluding CSS selector `(:not)` in your current definition. 
It will also exclude Font Awesome from assigning `font-size: small` to your elements in `#MainContent`.

For example:

```css
/**
 * Set to all elements in #MainContent 
 * @except: .fa (FontAwesome)
 */
 #MainContent *:not(.fa) {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: small !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to override the general setting:

```
#MainContent * {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: small !important;
    }
#MainContent * .fa {
  font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}
```

However, in your particular situation this will not really work either: You have some text ("Twitter Page", "LinkedIn Page") in spans which are *inside* tags that have class `fa`, so these words will be displayed with FontAwesome!

So you have to add a third rule like this to override the `fa` font setting again for those spans:

```
#MainContent * .fa > span {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: small !important;
}
```