# Html icon not showing in chrome

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I already link a font awesome cdn link in head but I can't find icon.

Someone help me I want menu icon to do responsive website.
What should I do? I also open in Firefox. Icon also not showing there. And also Microsoft Edge.
When I open devtool and find my  tag as in the picture.[icon not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcChL.png) I do nothing in css.
[Is this normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuKjg.png)

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">

    <nav>
        <div class="container navbar">
            <a href="#" class="logo">Portfolio</a>

            <div class="nav-div">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
            <ul class="active">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#resume">Skill</a></li>
                <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="btn">Hire Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you post your CDN link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font Awesome icons are not working, I have included all required files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/font-awesome-icons-are-not-working-i-have-included-all-required-files)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the version you have linked in your HTML is the same version of icon you are using. For example if you are trying to use a V6 icon but are linking a V5 library it won't work. Also, make sure you are not using a premium icon but linking the free library.

Comment: I already link the same version of V6 icon and link in html. And I also switch both to V5 and nothing change.

Comment: The `fa-solid fa-bars` is a V6 icon so stick with V6. Can you check your browser dev tools to check for errors.

Comment: I upload pic. Please check it.

Comment: Font awesome uses the `<i>` element so a browser will try to style it as italic in the absence of an overriding style, so yes. Please post your CDN link and check the console/network tab on your dev tools for errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the property **font-family** on the * in css, remove this because this can cause conflict with font-awesome.

This answer can help you more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979799/22432060

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by adding link from font awesome

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7823c06798.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="container navbar">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Portfolio</a>
        <div class="nav-div">
            <label for="menu">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
```