# Font awesome is not showing icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome and do not wish to add CSS with HTTP. I downloaded Font Awesome and included it in my code, yet Font Awesome is showing a bordered square box instead of an icon. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="font-size: 44px;">
   <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how to make the icon display instead of the bordered square box.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Make sure you're including the font files too.. not just the CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: here is the link to font-awesome tourbleshooting guide in git https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: please updated the question with your folder structure in which you have font-awesome folder, So which we can make out that "font-awesome.min.css" is correctly getting the ttf path or not.Only css would not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42355738/397872

Answer (score 97):

In my case i made the following mistake in my css code.

```
*{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

This will override all font family rules for the entire page.
My solution was to move the code to body like so.

```
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

NB: Whenever you use the `!important` flag in css, any other css rule declared of the same type on the same element will get overriden.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I had `*{font-family: Raleway}` and I changed it to `*.not(i) {font-family: Raleway}`

Comment: I had this problem too, but I didn't realise it for ages because in DevTools it really looked like FontAwesome was being used. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 68):

When you open `font-awesome.min.css` you can see following path:

```
'Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0' ...
```

It means that you have to create directory `Fonts` and then copy files `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` (`fontawesome-webfont.woff`, `fontawesome-webfont.eot`) to this folder. After that everything should work fine.

Comment: Since at least 0.8.1 font-awesome is not referenced.  There are three `summernote` files in the font folder with extensions `eot`, `ttf`, and `woff` that need to be distributed.

Comment: Be careful, in 4.6.3 (if not earlier) it's `fonts` not `Fonts` and on a case sensitive system that causes problems...

Comment: why does font awesome not say it on their website ? it is really not explicit.

Comment: Awesome! I thought the fonts had to be in the same folder as the css, they had to be one folder level up.

Comment: Also, make sure your library is up to date.  I had all my logos except the bandcamp logo.  Once I downloaded the updated 4.7 and replaced the files, it worked.

Comment: @Jason is right. Look into your font-awesome.min.css what folder your icons should be in. Secondly using fas fa-car for version 4.7 doesn't work. use fa fa-car instead.

Answer (score 61):

Be aware that the new version (5) of font awesome uses `"fas"` or `"fab"` instead of `"fa"` prefix.

Quoted from their website:

> The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands.

This is why my fonts were showing blank squares. Now fixed.

Example code:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="//www.facebook.com/xxx" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
```

See: https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-f?style=brands

Comment: That did it for me! Strange that it hasn't been updated in the docs

Comment: This was the only thing that worked. If you're using a modern version, use this.

Comment: LIVE SAVER! change to "fa fa-bars" borked

Comment: Thank you, for me some icons wirk with fas and others with fab, for instance fab fa-twitter is fine but fas fa-twitter shows a white square, go figure!

Comment: So if the new version is fas, then why do I need to change my classes from 'fas' to 'fa'

Comment: Thanks. This did it for me.

Comment: This is outdated now

Comment: This works for me (Bootstrap 5)

Answer (score 35):

First, check that you have class="fa" as well as whatever the icon's class is. So, not just

```
<i class="fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
```

But also

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
```

Then it works as expected. This solved my issue.

Comment: This worked for me. For me fab fa-envelop wasn't working, but then fa fa-envelop was working. Very strange but fixed my problem.

Comment: @JordanSchuetz "fab" is specific to brand icons, like "fab fa-facebook-f". In the newer versions, you'll find "fas" for the "solid" variation, so yours would get fixed to "fas fa-envelope" in the newer versions, or "fa fa-envelope" in an older one.

Comment: So frustrating that this was needed when a copy and paste of the code provided by Font Awesome themselves didn't include it! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 22):

Open your font-awesome.css
theres code like :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

you must have folder like :

```
font awesome -> css
 -> fonts
```

or the easiest way :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 13):

i was dealing with the same problem then i figured it out i have to use new version (5 and plus)

use this cdn it will work.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 10):

Check that the path to your `CSS` file is correct. Rather prefer absolute links, they are easier to understand since we know where we start from and search engines will also prefer them over relative links. And to reduce bandwidth rather use the link from font-awesome servers:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Moreover if you use it, **there will be no need of uploading extra fonts to your server** and you will be sure that you point to the right `CSS` file, and you will also benefit from the latest updates instantly.

Comment: I did same and still have square box only

Answer (score 9):

I'm using FontAwesome Pro, and the solution for me was to embed `all.min.css` instead of `fontawesome.min.css`.

Comment: for Free it is the same

Comment: This works for me using FontAwesome v5 and Angular v10. Thanks.

Comment: This works also for the free version, thanks, in combination with the response by @OneMoreQuestion

Answer (score 8):

i was facing the same issue..
so instead of downloading font awesome ,  i added a link in my html code and it worked.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i spend 24 hrs to fix this fontawesome

Answer (score 6):

It's something to do with v5, some of the icons don't work with older versions.

This link worked for me!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
```

Answer (score 4):

For a start, you shouldn't have both `font-awesome.css` *and* `font-awesome.min.css`

Generally, use `font-awesome.css` during development, then switch to `font-awesome.min.css` once you're happy with the site.

Problems like this are often caused by relative paths and locations, so check where your html file is in relation to the css.

If your html file is in the base directory, and the css in a subfolder off the root, you would need:
`href="./css/font-awesome.css"` (single period)

Answer (score 4):

All the above are correct however on top of that my issue was that I downloaded the free version of FA5 which doesn't have:

```
font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0')
```

I could not get v5 to work so I reverted to 4.7.0 with the help of the posts above and it fixed my issue.

Comment: I had issues with getting the v5+ of FontAwesome working as well. Had changed their "webfonts" folder to "fonts" in the css, and placed it the same way, and it didn't work properly. Replaced files with v4.7.0 and it works like a charm. Hrm.

Comment: In version 5, the font-family for the icons isn't "FontAwesome" anymore. In the free version, it is now "Font Awesome 5 Free" and "Font Awesome 5 Pro" in the pro version. I was having this issue when I was manually using the character codes in a few places, and they stopped working because of the font-family not being set.

Answer (score 4):

For those of you using SCSS and the NPM package, here is my solution:

`npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Then at the top of an SCSS file (ideally an SCSS file imported at the root of your application):

```
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

Comment: Interesting adding `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css` fixed it

Answer (score 3):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Working very well with this

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed to combine the answers from sst & Bruno Leveque:

- https://fontawesome.com/download
- download via Free for web, unpack
- copy all folders into /fontawesome/
- link the all.min.css instead of fontawesome.css

Example Django:

```
# in myapplication/vendor/fontawesome/ everything unpacked
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapplication/vendor/fontawesome/css/all.min.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully installed Font Awesome using their CDN and javascript include (as described on [this page](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)). Then I tried to copy the HTML and CSS to some legacy pages and suddenly I saw empty square boxes instead of the icons.

I saw Daniel's answer (above) and because my legacy CSS file was huge (and years old) I suspected that was the issue. However when I looked in Chrome DevTools it really looked like Font Awesome was loaded:

[image: Screenshot of CSS for Font Awesome Icon]

I was expecting to see the font in strikeout if there was an issue... However I had really exhausted all my options so I checked the Computed Styles and saw clearly that the Font Awesome font was definitely not being used. (See the Rendered font at the bottom)

[image: Font Awesome not being used]

My legacy CSS file was a mess and I preferred not to touch it, so I cheated by doing this - please don't tell anyone :)

```
<a class="nav-link fa fa-instagram" style="font-family:FontAwesome;" href="//www.instagram.com/xxxx/" target="_blank"></a>
```

Also to note, when I upgraded from Font Awesome version 4.7.0 to version 5.4.1 this issue went away! I used [this setup guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=svg-with-js) and this HTML

```
<a class="nav-link" href="//www.instagram.com/xxxx/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not fonts folder in your root folder like where stay css folder.

**Demo**

[image]

**And css folder is like**

[image]

**And fonts folder like**

[image]

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: 
You need to copy the whole **font-awesome folder** to your project css folder and not just the **font-awesome.min.css** file.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems adding `style='font-weight:normal;'` or otherwise changing the font directly on the element overrides the `.fas{font-weight:900}` definition in Font Awesome's CSS file.  I guess the font has specific defines within the font file that it works with. It seems the `font-weight` must be set between 501 and 1000, or the font may look like a square block.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was caused by using some regular styles (`far`) that are not included in the free set. Changing to `fas` fixed it.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

my issue was the one having most of the votes

```
*{
font-family: xxxxx
}
```

changing it to this solved the problem

```
body{
font-family: xxxx
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it worked by adding adding font-family, for example adding an Instagram icon, i needed to add font-family as FontAwsome:

```
.fa-instagram:before {
content: "\f16d";
font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may have used a VCS (git or somesuch) to transfer icon files to the server.
git says:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in webroot/fonts/FontAwesome.otf.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in webroot/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in webroot/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in webroot/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in webroot/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

You probably have to fix your fonts.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Mojave, I had this problem in Safari. The font-awesome images worked in Chrome but not in Safari, so I was sure it wasn't the site.

I got them to render by going to Preferences in the Safari menu, and disabling/unchecking "Prevent cross-site tracking" under the Privacy tab.

Not sure why this fixed it, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for Bootstrap!  Bootstrap will override .fa classes. If you're bringing in both packages separately thinking "I'll use Bootstrap for responsive block handling and Font-Awesome for icons", you need to address the .fa classes inside Bootstrap so they don't interfere with Font-Awesome's stand-alone implementation.

eg: font-family 'FontAwesome' in Bootstrap will interfere with font-family 'Font Awesome 5 Free' in Font-Awesome and you will get a white box instead of the icon you want.

There may be cleaner ways of handling this, but if you've gone down the checklist trying to fix the "white box" issue and still can't figure it out (like I did), this may be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Why the vote down? It's edge-case, but it's a cause not easily found elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the 5.10.1 version.

My solution (locally):

1. If you're using "fontawesome.css" or "fontawesome.min.css", try using "all.css" instead (located in the css folder).
2. The "css" folder and the "webfonts" folder from the fontawesome package that you downloaded must be in the same level as each other.

In my case, I already had a css folder so I just renamed the fontawesome css folder to "css-fa".

With both "css-fa" and "webfonts" in my css folder, simply link it correctly in your text editor and it should work.

Ex: link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css-fa/all.css"

Answer (score 0):

solved changing the targetted !importantized font-family selector from 
`* { ... }` 
to 
`*:not(i) { ... }`

(with scss preprocessor); hope u solved

Answer (score 0):

The code below is font-awesome 4.70.0. To go to font-awesome 5.11.2, click  [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?from=io).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following this tutorial to host Font Awesome Pro 5.13 myself.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

For some reason I could not get `<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/font-awesome/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` to load `webfonts` that in turn resulted in only squares showing up. But when I used `<script defer src="%PUBLIC_URL%/font-awesome/all.min.js"></script>` everything started working. Both links were added in HTML `<head>`.

Comment: the problem with this js is that the file is to heavy lo load

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add fa 5.0.13  to drupal 8 with scss.
The styles are not included by default in the main fa.scss had to add them manually.

```
@import "libraries/fontawesome/fa-brands";
@import "libraries/fontawesome/fa-light";
@import "libraries/fontawesome/fa-regular";
@import "libraries/fontawesome/fa-solid";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put font-awesome file in css folder and change

href="../css/font-awesome.css"
to
href="css/font-awesome.css"

One more thing You can Replace this Font-awesome css File And and try this one

```css
.social-media{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.social-media li .fa{ 
  background: #fff;
  color: #262626;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px; 
}

.social-media .fa:hover { 
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000; 
}

.social-media .fa.fa-twitter:hover{
  background:#55acee;
  color:#fff;
 
}

.social-media .fa.fa-facebook:hover{
  background:#3b5998;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="social-media">
  <li><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: That isn't how code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing all the necessary files like so

```html
<head>
  <!-- reference your copy Font Awesome here (from our CDN or by hosting yourself) -->
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- custom styling for all icons -->
    i.fas,
    i.fab {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    <!-- custom styling for specific icons -->$$
    .fa-fish {
      color: salmon;
    }

    .fa-frog {
      color: green;
    }

    .fa-user-ninja.vanished {
      opacity: 0.0;
    }

    .fa-facebook {
      color: rgb(59, 91, 152);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-fish"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-frog"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-user-ninja vanished"></i>
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the wrong path.

 And also, download the latest version from the website. The icons must also be from the same version.

https://fontawesome.com/versions

The version of Font Awesome can be seen on the link of the path. Like version 6.1.2 in the below link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Instead of using CDN, I used CDNJS. Go to this website and download the latest version.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Answer (score -1):

```
You needed to close your `<link />` 
As you can see in your <head></head> tag. This will solve your problem

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
```