# Bootstrap, Font awesome not showing the icons but the icon is spinning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Hi I am using Bootstrap to design a 'Site Maintenance' page.

I am using the 'Spinning Icon Font' to display the spinning gears. While this works very fine on my local XAMPP server, it is not showing when I upload it to online server.

**Should be:**

[image]

**But it is showing as**

[image]

However those rectangular frames shown in the second pic **are spinning**, but it is not showing the gears.

**My index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  <title>Maintenance</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,800,800italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- App CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin.css">

</head>

<body class="">

<div class="maintenance-wrapper">

  <div class="maintenance">

    <div class="maintenance-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin gear-1"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin gear-2 text-primary"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin gear-3 text-secondary"></i>
    </div>  <!-- /.The Spinning-icons -->

    <h1 class="maintenance-title">Site Maintenance</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**Where am I doing wrong?**

Live example can be see at http://vikramrao.com

Comment: I'm looking at dev console at it throws an error 404 for "fontawesome-webfont" source.

Comment: I've used the fontawesome CDN and it's working fine! The problem is with your `/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font awesome showing just square box instead icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867795/font-awesome-showing-just-square-box-instead-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"font-awesome.min.css" is trying to load fonts from:

http://vikramrao.com/fonts/

so:

- http://vikramrao.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
- http://vikramrao.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
- http://vikramrao.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

Don't exists, it throws 404 error (not found)

You should create this folder and upload this files.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code structure and found that you provided improper path for font in stylesheet. See my screen capture [image: Screenshot]

Comment: The issue is already resolved. However thanks for taking time to reply nicely in detail.

Comment: Is there any votes for it? Because I saw that someone is down voted my answer.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have the capability to tell you as to who voted you down. That needs way much more reputation points.