# Icons are showing as a square instead of Icon images

Tags: css, font-awesome

I find the same issue as it is mentioned in this thread: [Font awesome is not showing icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867795/font-awesome-is-not-showing-icon)

Icon images are displaying like this [image] sometime.

When I use this link:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It works fine with the above link although I was using newer version of Font Awesome 4.7 which should work as it is the later version than in the above link. Also when I download the same version and upload to my server it didn't work but when I use the link then it works. 
Also, this issue appears for the same page (most of time it works but sometime all icons are like this [image]), otherwise everything works fine and Icons are displaying properly

Is there any way to debug the issue? I replaced css files, uploaded newer version but couldn't find any solution yet that why sometime all icons disappears and replaced it with this image [image]

Comment: Make sure the icon is using the correct `font-family`. The newest Font-Awesome uses `font-family: Font Awesome 5 "something"` where Font Awesome 4.7.0 uses `font-family: FontAwesome`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not using the code version that matches with your CDN .Make sure that icons match with the version of CDN you are importing.
[Here](https://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome-icons-v4-2/) you can see the **4.20** version of fontawesome

Comment: .fa { font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome; } 
This is disabled sometime, I don't know how that is happening but when it is disabled then all the icons are not displaying correctly.