# Font Awesome fonts

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I recently installed font-awesome from the site using npm. When I am using it in my HTML file, it ends up showing squares on the page instead of the icon. Can someone help me with this?

The code where I am using the fontawesome icons:

```
<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><span class="fas fa-home"></span> Home</a></li>
```

I have included the CSS as well.

Comment: Did you mean to post some CSS as well?

Comment: No, I meant the I have included the CSS link in the HTML as well.

Comment: show us how you linked to the css in the html. and please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Black squares usually indicate a fault in font type. But I cant say this for sure. Try san serif, otherwise you can check out the answers in this post:
[Font awesome is not showing icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867795/font-awesome-is-not-showing-icon)

Best answer there:
In my case i made the following mistake in my css code.

```
*{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

This will override all font family rules for the entire page. My solution was to move the code to body like so.

```
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

NB: Whenever you use the !important flag in css, any other css rule declared of the same type on the same element will get overriden.
Answer By: Daniel Barde

--

It also can depend on how you import the library, is it via the CDN or via a folder?

Via a CDN: Check if the path / url is correct (Maybe an unauthorised link?).
Via folder / download:
Maybe use"/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css"
instead of
"/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/fontawesome.css".

Comment: I have not used any custom font-family style in any of the CSS.

Comment: I've edited my response. If its not de library, I hope someone with more experience will look at this question. Good luck with the project.