# WooCommerce Buttons Not Showing Correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched high and low (for 2 days) and can't find the answer.

So I built my site on the same server it was going to be hosted on and once we had our URL, I created a new folder and migrated everything to the new folder (making what changes I needed). It seemed to be up and running but there are a few things that I just can't figure out for the life of me. If you click on the link, and then click on the product, it brings up a light box of the photo.

http://www.wetdeck.com/product/16-nozzle-kit/

In the top right and left (and other places) of the picture, it just shows a square. Some icons on the back end also don't show. Any help would be great. All the file permissions are correct on the server. The icons next to woocommerce on the back end don't show and same with other buttons.

These files are on the server but won't show anything. As I posted the image url below.  I've tried replacing it with a different file but nothing.  I have tried updating the database to replace the old URL with the new URL and it updated 6 entries in the wp_post table but nothing changed.  Thanks in advance!

http://www.wetdeck.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/help.png

Comment: Go to admin/setting/permalink/save. try it, cos sometimes it works. You could also use the search and replace plugin to check for an instances of the old folder name in your DB. This usually affects images the most, as the filename tends to get hard coded into the DB with the folder names.

Comment: I used said plugin which found a few more instances so I updated the old URL to the new one but it still hasn't changed anything.  Any other advice would be great!

Comment: Well, I looked at you link, and it's got something to do with the font icons, which it uses in the squares missing images. I see their classes all begin with "pp_", so it must be a missing images folder, or icons, relating to the pretty plugin. Check the plugins folders, re-install it... play around with it :) `.pp_close:before{font-family:WooCommerce;content:"\e013";` from the relevant css file, so the font-family isn't loading from woocommerce. That's at least a lead....

Comment: Check the console to see if any scripts aren't loading.

Comment: Great! I'll give it another look and see what I can find.  I appreciate your help and I'll keep you posted! Console is clear as far as I can see, no errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Have you resolved this? When I look at your prettyPhoto item the icons are all there. It was probably an issue with loading the custom WooCommerce font.

Answer (score 1):

@gavinSimpson did a fantastic job of helping me in the right direction.  After a lot of digging, there was another plugin that had a few JS errors that stopped the fonts from loading.  I disabled the wp plugin to find the culprit and then coded what I needed to.

Thanks for the help.