# Font Icons display as "fl" in font-awesome

Tags: font-awesome

I downloaded the font-awesome package, and I included the css file in my page as instructed, but it doesn't work. It displays as "fl".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you add any font awesome class add "fa" before it,

like [ **class="fa fa-search"** ] to get ride of this issue.

credit goes to Nabil kadimi's answer at this [Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares) post

Comment: when `fa` is missing, it displays blank square but the text `fl`. `fl` appears while the icon is loading. when you set network slow from browser dev tool, you can see it. it relates about network speed so I guess when the fontawesome is called from external link, it happens.