# Font awesome icons disable getting square only

Tags: html, css, html-escape-characters, fontawesome-4.4.0

I have added font awesome icons in my html page for data table plugin UI using css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/datatable/pratik/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/datatable/font-awesome.css" />
```

But due to some errors I changed all symbols into special escape characters.
May be that's why it's showing blank square.Any trick to resolve this error.
My code for font awesome icon is:

```
 text: &#39;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-list-ol-3x&quot; aria-hidden=&quot;true&quot; style=&quot;color:#81ad30&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&#39;,
```

[image: Output showing icons]

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your escaping all the tags is creating the issue. Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares)

Comment: make sure all the font files path are correct, or check console window

Comment: @Jacob if i remove all escape char it will generate error of markup lang.

Comment: @PratikPowar Then it isn't going to work. When you escape the tags, the browser will just treat it as text, and the associated font-awesome styles won't get applied

Comment: ok then only one solution is to move all code into a js function from html page