# Internet Explorer 11+ Not Rendering Text-Overflow: Elipses Properly With Font Awesome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less, font-awesome

I'm currently having an issue with rendering text-overflow: elipses on IE: 11+. The project is using Font Awesome 4.7.
Rendering of the elipses works perfect in Chrome/Firefox, but IE is the one with the issue.

The interesting thing is, if I inspect the element in the image below, it seems that the `font-family` value is what appears to fix it for that element

The `<div>` in the image inherits:

`font-family: "FontAwesome", Verdana, sans-serif`

If I change it to:

`font-family: Verdana, sans-serif`

it fixes it, but at the expense of losing the icons (*which is obviously not wanted*)

[image]

The following related questions have all been consulted:

- *[Issue on FA GitHub Repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1079)* - Can't use the `X:before { content: '' }` in the project. some of the components being used are using `before content` already
- *[Using a `<meta>` tag to fix it](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#internet-explorer-compatibility-mode)* - Tried it, no results.
- *[Issues others were having with the CSS file pointing to the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares/30098214)* - The issue here is that the icons actually render, it is just the issue with the elipses

Comment: Can you provide the complete HTML and jQuery code

Comment: Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ywkg5yLx/ works great in IE11. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth [Here is a plunk that replicates the issue on my end](https://plnkr.co/edit/OnxGkdYKXSSv0wUOBckx?p=preview), Using angular 1.x and bootstrap in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. It seems I was using Font Awesome Incorrecly. In my CSS I was setting

```
body {
  font-family: "FontAweomse", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Removing `"FontAwesome"` and then using the correct syntax of including the ***fa*** in the class name like this:

`<span class="fa icon-delete"></span>`

corrects the issue.Before this all uses of font awesome we're like

`<span class="icon-delete"></span>`