# Font-Awesome loading but not showing in wordpress , icons are like square

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

Font-Awesome icon there is in my website and it loads but icons not appearing in  it (show like Square) ! What's the reason ? My website url is : [sitefestival](http://www.sitefestival.com/)

Comment: Can you show how you are loading it in your source code? Probably the actual fontawesome font file is not correctly downloaded and thus you end up with an empty icon (the square you are mentioning)

Comment: @whites11 As default source code is in this url that I don't put it and I know why there is here ! : [link](http://www.sitefestival.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seems to be this CSS syntax at line 6 of *rtl.css* file which overrides the Font-Awesome definition:

```
ul.newsticker a, .pricing-table .head span,.featured_table .recommended,.product_meta,.woocommerce div.product form.cart .button,.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations label,.woocommerce div.product form.cart .reset_variations,option,.woo-title .filter_wrapper select, .pa_selection select,.pagination-tt ul li a, .pagination-tt ul li span,div.wpcf7-validation-errors, div.wpcf7-mail-sent-ng,.woocommerce p.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce p.woocommerce-info, .woocommerce p.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce ul.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce ul.woocommerce-info, .woocommerce ul.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce div.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce div.woocommerce-info, .woocommerce div.woocommerce-message,.woocommerce .woocommerce-error .button, .woocommerce .woocommerce-info .button, .woocommerce .woocommerce-message .button, .woocommerce-page .woocommerce-error .button, .woocommerce-page .woocommerce-info .button, .woocommerce-page .woocommerce-message .button,.woocommerce .shop-links a span,.woocommerce td.product-name .wc-item-meta .wc-item-meta-label, .woocommerce td.product-name .wc-item-meta dt, .woocommerce td.product-name dl.variation .wc-item-meta-label, .woocommerce td.product-name dl.variation dt,#add_payment_method .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table td, #add_payment_method .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table th, .woocommerce-cart .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table td, .woocommerce-cart .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table th, .woocommerce-checkout .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table td, .woocommerce-checkout .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table th,.woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt, .woocommerce a.button.alt, .woocommerce button.button.alt, .woocommerce input.button.alt,#add_payment_method table.cart td, #add_payment_method table.cart th, .woocommerce-cart table.cart td, .woocommerce-cart table.cart th, .woocommerce-checkout table.cart td, .woocommerce-checkout table.cart th,.woocommerce .price_label,.woocommerce .widget_price_filter .price_slider_amount .button,div.userpro *,html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video
{
font-family: sitefestival!important;
}
```

Removing the **i** selector from that list should solve the problem.

Comment: So Thanks , you're right ! I didn't attention to this part at all !

Answer (score 0):

@Mpi You need to modify the supplied CSS file to point to the font location on your site. [Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares)