# Font Awesome Icons showing up as squares on menu bar

Tags: ios, wordpress, macos

My social icons are showing up as squares in the top right hand corner of my website. They are part of my menu. However, I have FA icons on other parts of my site and they are showing up perfectly. Any ideas how to fix this, simply? I don't have a lot of tech knowhow. My site is self hosted on Wordpress and I use IOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares)

Comment: It is strange that they are looking fine on other parts of the site, can you share the URL, as if font was not loaded fine, it should not work fine on whole site.

Comment: Hi. My url is: https://www.melaniemay.com

Answer (score 0):

Please verify this two stuff:
1. Check if font-awesome is properly integrated on your website. You can view this by looking over page source and find if there is a link related to font awesome.It may look something like this but by different as well.
yourwebsite-directory-uri/font-awesome.min.css
`Reference Link:` http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

2. See if you have added font awesome properly using css.

   .test-class {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     content: "\f005";
   }

Hope this will give you some hints.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.