# Wicked PDF - showing fontawesome icons as square box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, wicked-gem

I am using `wicked-pdf` gem (v1.2.2) to generate a PDF report which contains a font awesome icon.

I have kept the fontawesome file in this path:

> `vendor/assets/fonts/fontawesome.css.erb`

and corresponding fonts in this path:

`vendor/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fa-brands-400.eot`

A sample snippet from **fontawesome.css.erb**: (this is how fonts are referred)

---

```
/*!
 * Font Awesome Free 5.5.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
 */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('<%= asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.eot' %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.eot' %>?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), url('<%= asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.woff2' %>') format("woff2"), url('<%= asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.woff' %>') format("woff"), url('<%= asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.ttf' %>') format("truetype"), url('<%= asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome' %>') format("svg"); }
```

> I am using asset pipeline.

I have included the fontawesome to the report layout (`report.html.erb`) as below:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64('fontawesome.css') %>
```

When I load the PDF in debug mode, I get **square boxes** only and I do not see anything in PDF.[image]

I referred this question: [Font Awesome not working, icons showing as squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366158/font-awesome-not-working-icons-showing-as-squares)

and added the CDN link to fontawesome in place of local file. 
It worked only in **debug mode**.

When I tried in PDF mode, it took a long period of loading time and finally it didn't show the font. Hence, this is not a solution for me.

Looking forward to your inputs. Thanks

---

**Changes:**
I updated the `fontawesome.css.erb` with absolute reference to font file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('<%= ActionController::Base.helpers.wicked_pdf_asset_path('fontawesome/fa-brands-400.woff') %>');
}
```

In debug mode, I am getting the following error in Chrome browser.

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///home/Projects/my_app/vendor/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fa-brands-400.woff`

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wickedpdf opens html as a local file, so all urls should be either relative to some temporary folder, full local file paths (these are generated by wicked pdf helpers) or absolute urls with hosts.

Your `fontawesome.css` contains urls to font files that does not contain host by default. You can either create a separate version of that for pdf generation, or include in html template `head` itself:

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;
  src: url('<%= wicked_pdf_asset_path 'fontawesome/fa-brands-400.woff' %>');
}
</style>
```

(no need for iefix and can use less formats, because we are sure that wkhtmltopdf is not IE, also there was a bug with fallback urls for fonts not working)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did change the fontawesome file and now getting `Not allowed to load local resource` error. I have added the code to the question in **Changes** section above, please have a look.

Comment: @dp7 for debug mode that error is normal, for quicker markup it's convenient to alter `asset_path`/`wicked_pdf_asset_path ` depending on rendering mode

Answer (score 2):

The `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag` and `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` helpers don't seem to play nice with fontawesome due to the relative path reference to the webfonts.

The following worked for me (using webpacker)...

`yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

In `app/javascript/packs/reports.js` (name the pack whatever you want):

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss'
// add other icons as necessary
```

And then in your layout file:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag asset_pack_url('reports.css')
```

Using `asset_pack_url` instead of `asset_pack_path` is important because wicked_pdf needs the full url and won't work with a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to base64 encode the font files.

This is in Rails 6. In your PDF layout file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64("bootstrap-icons.css") %>
```

In `app/assets/stylesheets` add the `bootstrap-icons.css` file but replace

```css
src: url("./fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2?7141511ac37f13e1a387fb9fc6646256") format("woff2"),
url("./fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff?7141511ac37f13e1a387fb9fc6646256") format("woff");
```

with something like the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-display: block;
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src: url(data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09Q46rC8....) format("woff2"),
       url(data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAA....) format("woff");
}
```

Ensure there is no space after `base64,`. Also ensure that your base64 encoded string is all on one line with no spaces.

To get your base64 encoded string you can do the following in the Rails console:

```rb
encoded_string = Base64.encode64(File.read("/path/to/file/bootstrap-icons.woff"))
File.write("/path/to/file/encoded.txt", encoded_string)
encoded_string2 = Base64.encode64(File.read("/path/to/file/bootstrap-icons.woff2"))
File.write("/path/to/file/encoded2.txt", encoded_string2)
```