# Why am I unable to see my Font Awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=b oxwebpage.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/fontawesome.css" />
<div class="ram">
  <i class="fa-regular fa-info"></i>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to fix it just shows empty box?

Comment: @TasosK. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815998/8565010 deprecated as of version 5, OP is using version 6. You can still use it, it won't harm anything, it just won't solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 1):

`<i class="fa-regular fa-info"></i>` is a pro icon, so if you don't have a subscription with FA then it's not going to display for you even if you try to use a different CDN (it'll show an X or nothing at all)

https://fontawesome.com/icons/info?s=regular

I switched it out with solid, they basically look the same but if you absolutely have to have the pro version then you'll have to shell out for it: https://fontawesome.com/plans

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=b oxwebpage.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="ram">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-info"></i>
</div>
```

You could also cheat it by adding a -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black; (FA icons can be treated as classes) but it's a non-standard feature according to MDN but I think the only people you'll be leaving out are IE users

```css
.fa-info {
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=boxwebpage.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="ram">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-info"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following cdn and remove regular from class:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="ram">
  <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
</div>
```