# IIS 500 error - failed to execute URL on .ttf, .svg and .woff font files?

Tags: iis-7, mime-types, truetype, woff

I'm trying to deploy a web application which references http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Everything works great locally, but when I deploy I receive several 500 errors.

```
> GET
> http://localhost/csweb/Content/font_awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
> 500 (Internal Server Error)

> GET
> http://localhost/csweb/Content/font_awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff
> 500 (Internal Server Error)

> GET
> http://localhost/csweb/Content/font_awesome/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomregular
> 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

A quick search of StackOverflow lead me to this thread: [Why is @font-face throwing a 404 error on woff files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files)

as such I added to my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
...
```

I see IIS reflecting these changes after calling iisreset, but no effect was seen on the deployed application.

I'm not finding any other obvious answers -- anyone know anything I don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh hey, I figured it out almost immediately afterward. I need to add the following lines to web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="*.woff" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.ttf" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.svg" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      ...
```

Comment: This crashed my IIS server entirely.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue, it causes by the web.config file that has <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" ...> statement in the static font folder. Delete it everything goes well. Also, I tried to add mimeMap statement on the website root folder web.config file but cause the CSS loading error.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of IIS didn't have a MIME type for WOFF2. So the fonts folder contained a web.config file containing <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff2" />.
Newer versions now have a MIME type for WOFF2 so the web.config file is causing an error, it needs to read
<remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff2" />