# With ASP.NET MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3 default install, why do styles get a 403 error and fonts throw a 404?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

With a default install of ASP.NET MVC 5 and an updated Bootstrap 3, loading my project's home page does not display CSS styles or the included font glyphicons (404 file not found error).

The CSS styles get a 403 "Forbidden to view folder contents" error to the /Content/css address.

The fonts get a 404 error to /fonts folder.

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you install Bootstrap 3 into the Content folder, it includes a folder structure like this:

```
~/Content/css/boostrap.min.css
~/Content/fonts/glyphincons-halflinkgs-regular.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)
```

The 403 "Forbidden" error, is likely because the default CSS bundle route "~/Content/css" matches a valid folder name, and MVC cannot resolve the conflict between a route and folder.

**Fix the 403** by renaming your route to something that doesn't match a real folder like, "~/Content/cssbundle".

When you change the bundle name, the 404 "file not found" error occurs for the fonts as the relative path from the CSS files to the fonts is no longer valid.

**Fix the 404** by moving your fonts folder to the root of your project. (I wish I had a better solution here)

Comment: (Note: I posted my own answer under the SO community tenant of sharing knowledge in the Q&A format. If you can improve upon my answer, PLEASE do so. This is to help all of us.)

Comment: Also note that IIS 7 does not add a MIME type mapping for .woff files by default.  Here is a link to set that up: http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/web-development/404-errors-in-iis7-for-embedded-woff-font-files/

Comment: Great explanation. Followed your instructions step by step and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Any way round this without messing with iis?

Comment: I found I also had to fix the `woff2` file type by using this fix (Solution 2 & adding `2` to the end of all extensions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files#7374640

Answer (score 3):

I too was struggling with this miserably.

There has been an update to the Twitter.Bootstrap nuget package from 3.0.1 => 3.0.1.1. 
The Twitter.Bootstrap package is now just Bootstrap and has been moved to be managed by the Outercurve foundation.

Chris Kirby has changed the folder structures by eliminating the Content/Bootstrap directory and placing all boostrap.css files directly in the Content folder. He also moved the fonts directory into the root of the site.

See more here; (http://chriskirby.net/bootstrap-nuget-package-moving-to-outercurve/)

This resolved the issue I was having and resolved all my glyphicon font issues.

Comment: Nice followup! That is useful info. I believe I was using the source directly from the Bootstrap project at the time, but this might be a good alternative route.