# NetworkError: 403 Forbidden fontawesome css file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, font-awesome

I recently working on asp.net mvc5 and upload on server.

I am getting Network Error: 403 Forbidden - 
sHZULMKsewI1">http://bsdemo.com/Content/fontawesome/?v=k4QxRX3q4UFmGtMg0dA7qxnadoa7Q9_sHZULMKsewI1

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://bsdemo.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

On local machine  working fine .

Thanks
Vik

Comment: Any authentication mechanism on your site perhaps blocking the file?

Comment: i am not using any authentication .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388225/with-asp-net-mvc-5-and-bootstrap-3-default-install-why-do-styles-get-a-403-erro?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Check your IIS App Pool settings and make sure the directory structure has the correct permissions for the user the app pool is running as. Not much of an answer just a troubleshooting step. I have run in to this from local dev to production too man times to count.

As a test set your app pool to run as network service then go to your web root and add the network service account to the folder.