# Custom font working locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net, css, .net-4.0, fonts, custom-font

I am working on Asp.net 4.0 with VS2010. I am trying to use a custom font.

I have a 'Fonts' folder which has font file.

The css is (css file in css folder)

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Trade Gothic20";
src: url('../Fonts/TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn20.otf');
```

The font works locally but when I move it to the server it doesn't work.

- File doesn't load. 404 error.

I have set Build Action Property to content.

What could be the reason?

I saw one question (below)

[question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files)

Do i need to write in config files? I have 'otf' extension file.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the Font folder and the font files exist on the server? Probably they aren't deployed.

Comment: @AndiKrusch : they are deployed but now working with Firefox and Chrome after adding MIME type in web.config but still not working with IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. First check if your font is accessible through the combined URL.
2. Second open the webpage and check (using chrome Inspector for instance) if the URL is building correctly.
3. If none of the shows errors check if the webserver allows the MIME type to be accessed/downloaded
4. Check this answer to see if it is not a browser support issue: [How to add some non-standard font to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website)

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok I had to add <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" /> in web.config file but i don't get to work in IE. Working fine in Firefox and chrome.

Comment: Can you try changing the font url to absoulute instead of relative.
Like it is suggested here:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1179612.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Please also try to use different fonts format as some browsers only can view specific font formats

Like this `@font-face { font-family: 'Trade Gothic20';
                src: url('http://www.URL/fontname.eot');
                src: url('http://www.URL/fontname.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://www.URL/fontname.woff') format('woff'), url('http://www.URL/fontname.svg') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Try entering full URL, without ..  (instead of a reference):

Example:

```
src: url('http://devserver/MyPortal/Content/MvcGrid/Fonts/GridGlyphs.woff') format('woff');
```

or without the server name:

```
src: url('MyPortal/Content/MvcGrid/Fonts/GridGlyphs.woff') format('woff');
```