# FireFox Can not load fonts 404 Not Found

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i have the following inside my CSS file:-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(_tMhxyW6i8lbI7YsUdFlGA.eot);
  src: local('Ubuntu'), url(_tMhxyW6i8lbI7YsUdFlGA.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff) format('woff');
}
```

i have added the fonts and CSS files inside the same folder (Conten/CSS), but when i check the F12 on firefox it mentioned that it can not get the .woff files, although the files are inside the CSS folder ?

Can anyone advice what is causing this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: try giving `absolute` path rather than `relative` path..

Comment: but firefox F12 tool mentioned that it can not locate "/Content/css/_xyN3apAT_yRRDeqB3sPRg.woff". so i think it have understand the URL correctly. so the problem is not with the URL.

Comment: I think that you also need the .ttf of the font and possibly the .svg as well, different browsers use different font formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with MVC.

Here is an answer relating to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374640/1838483

I solved this issue by adding a MIME Type declaration via IIS Manager `.woff  application/x-woff`. You can also add this in your config file like so:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  </staticContent>    
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i tried adding this to the web.config file inside my MVC , but i will receive and  internal server error, after deploying it into IIS ..

Comment: Can you find out what the error message was? Also are you testing this locally?

Comment: i added the type to my site MIME type on IIS, and it worked well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming localhost**

If you are running the site from local server i.e., `localhost`, it wont get loaded in forefox

go to -> `about:config` -> `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`
Set it to `false` and you would be able to see fonts then!!

**Also**,giving `absolute path` url's are far better and suggested option than having a `relative` path!

Comment: no not local host, the web application is deployed on IIS 7 and i am accessing the server from my PC .