# Registering MIME type in web.config not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, iis-7.5

I encountered a problem with 404 error messages on `.woff` files that seemed easily fixable from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files).  I opted to go the route of registering the MIME type in my web.config file so I wouldn't have to remember to update the production site with a new registration when the application I'm building was deployed.

I added the following lines to my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

... and then I deployed.  However, contrary to all the documentation I've read on this, it appears that this doesn't work.  I still get the 404 error.  Manually updating the IIS site (2008R2, IIS 7.5) and registering the MIME type fixed the issue, but it certainly didn't want to play nice with my web.config settings.

Is there an extra step I'm missing to get this to register solely with the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace,

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
```

by,

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Venkat (cannot comment due to too low rep)
That would be stupid, considering the official MIME-type is `application/font-woff`.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b