# Error on my Font-face - Give me 404 get to the side

Tags: css, html, http-status-code-404

this is how I try to make font-awesome and simple line-icons into the website, but they continue to give me 404 errors to the page.

I have checked with CSS if it fits all the way. and pull it out on the page.

if I take the files away so there is no mistake but I add them again, then they come forward.

i have try its [Why is @font-face throwing a 404 error on woff files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files)

I have looked at their CSS and they look like this:

**simple-line-icons.css**

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
        src:url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');
        src:url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

**font-awesome.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Here I show that I have just the files it just right place Could it perhaps have something to do with that I have https on the side ??

[image]

i have buy its [design (Porto)](http://themeforest.net/item/porto-responsive-html5-template/4106987)

Comment: "I have checked with CSS if it fits all the way. and pull it out on the page.

if I take the files away so there is no mistake but I add them again, then they come forward." can you explain what you mean with these sentences?

Comment: @TomGroot If I grab the css file from the area, so it seems not, but I delete CSS file. so there will be no errors appear on the page. If you do not understand me so far away to the back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar issues, and just playing around with the order of the URLs seemed to sort things out. Give this a try for your first font, and if that works, you then have a basis for Font Awesome. Though I generally prefer to use CDN's where possible:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
    src: url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons') format('svg'),
         url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I chose to run both of them at cdn. and thank you to tell cdn, the one I had not thought of.