# What's wrong with element positioning using font-awesome on IIS?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis, font-awesome

I'm already aware of the fact that fonts are not correctly recognized in IIS and I've already configured it web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />

    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But this is different. In my html prototype I have correctly positioned icons of the arrows:

[image]

However, when running the same prototype under IIS I arrows are not positioned correctly and are oval shaped instead of circles.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check with your inspector if those font files got served correctly (200) from IIS? I remember there was some [trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files) with woff and IIS, where you had to apply woff and it's mimetype in IIS setup.

Comment: Yes, that entries in web.config I posted above do that job and yes they are served correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try embedding the woff file in you CSS file. This eliminates the IIS issue.
[Explanation for base64 font integration](http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri)