# 403 Forbidden - Fonts on XXAMP

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass, truetype

Just tried to use a new font, put it in a folder and linked to it, but I am getting this:

> GET http://localhost/mywebsite/fonts/garamond/EBGaramond12-Regular.ttf
>   403 (Forbidden)

I implemented it like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Garamond;
  src: url(../fonts/garamond/EBGaramond12-Regular.ttf);
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

The path is correct, but I'm not sure why I get a 403. I am using XXAMP on OSX, other fonts work fine.

Comment: Did you check the data permissions of the file or/and folder?

Comment: No - this might be the problem! how can I do this in the terminal?

Comment: ls -l is the command

Comment: Thanks. I get: drwx------@

Comment: of the file or the folder? ...nvm folder :D fail

Comment: Stupid me. Now I get: -rwxr-xr-x@

Comment: You can try to set them to 777 just for tryin. the folder and the file

Comment: chmod 777 foldername, and same for the font.

Comment: amazing, that worked! Sorry, that was really silly of me.

Comment: I can write a complete answer for other users with the same task

Comment: Sure, go ahead. I will select it.

Comment: done :) i hope i included the key things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GET http://localhost/mywebsite/fonts/garamond/EBGaramond12-Regular.ttf 403 (Forbidden)

Is a sign for a file permission problem.
You can get the file permissions by ls -l in the terminal. Changing them by chmod to 777 should work. Later on you can change them back to a lower permission for security.

Answer (score -3):

Try by removing the starting double dots and slash in the font path.

Like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Garamond;
  src: url(fonts/garamond/EBGaramond12-Regular.ttf);
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

The `../` needed only if your fonts directory is outside of the project directory or your styles file is located in a subdirectory instead of project root.

On other hands, it might be the mime types issue.

See this help for that: [Why is @font-face throwing a 404 error on woff files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: it is in a subdirectory of my project root though.

Comment: It says forbidden, meaning the file path is correct but its just missing the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But this is not the correct solution to my problem.