# Why is the custom font not being applied to my page in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a custom font to a webpage. I am using Google Chrome.

I am specifying the path in my CSS like so:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: ottosans_regular;
    src: url(../Content/Fonts/ottosans-regular-1v32-webfont.woff);
}
```

And applying it like so:

```
    body {
    font-family: ottosans_regular;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font file may not be loading properly...
Try to add the mime type for .woff in your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015816/why-is-font-face-throwing-a-404-error-on-woff-files)