# font-face with wrong MIME type in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

This is the `@font-face` declaration I have used:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: SolaimanLipi;
    src: url("font/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf");
}
```

This is working perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome.
After "inspect element" I got the following message:

> Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What about adding `AddType font/ttf .ttf` in a htaccess ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts

Answer (score 77):

As usual, different browsers have different needs. Here is a cross browser @fontface declaration, taken from the [Paul Irish blog](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) -

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
         url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), url('GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

.eot is for IE, the rest of the browsers use either .woff or .ttf 
If you need to generate the different types from the source font, you can use Font Squirrel's [font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

You also need to an .htaccess to the location of the fonts adding the following types:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful to me. I'm using the .htaccess trick as I have the privilege.

Comment: Does anybody have an IIS-compatible solution?

Comment: @david i just fixed the a related issue in iis. appears that there isn't a default mapping for *.woff files*. adding & properly configuring the mapping worked for me ...

Comment: The MIME type that Xander refers to, added to the IIS server's list of MIME types, is "application/x-font-woff", per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts.

Comment: I added these 4 lines at the end of my file, but I still get the error. How long does it take to make this working? Or what do you mean by "location of the fonts"?

Answer (score 4):

You can ignore the warning and may want to consider this post on the topic, [Proper MIME type for fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts/4657091#4657091)

Which also mentions the following:

> "Note: Because there are no defined MIME types for TrueType, OpenType,
>   and WOFF fonts, the MIME type of the file specified is not
>   considered."

source: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face

Answer (score 4):

Your font files are not being trasferred with the proper MIME type. This is a web server configuration issue that can easily be fixed.

For nginx, merge this with existing types config, usually found in the `/etc/nginx` directory:

```
types {
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject    eot;
    application/x-font-woff    woff;
    font/otf    otf;
    font/ttf    ttf;
}
```

For Apache, add these lines to `.htaccess` found in your Document Root:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

Comment: It is not a big deal but confusing issue. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

if you can edit an .htaccess file you should try add

```
addType font/ttf .ttf
```

otherwise you could use a svg/svgz font instead

Answer (score 0):

If you run a server with nodeJS, this is a nice module to map your mime types

https://github.com/broofa/node-mime