# Chrome 10/Windows @font-face encoding trouble

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, character-encoding, font-face

Has anyone come across something like this exclusively in Chrome 10/Win?

[image: Screenshot of non-breaking spaces being replaced by question mark and square characters]

All the non-breaking spaces in these two webfonts aren't rendered properly.  Working in IE7/8/9, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome/OSX.

Contents of my fonts.css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Hellenic';
    src: url('../fonts/eot/hellenic.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/ttf/hellenic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/woff/hellenic.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/svg/hellenic.svg#MCMHellenicWide') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lasalle';
    src: url('../fonts/eot/lasalle.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/ttf/lasalle.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/woff/lasalle.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/svg/lasalle.svg#FilmotypeLaSalle') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothic';
    src: url('../fonts/eot/leaguegothic.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/ttf/leaguegothic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/woff/leaguegothic.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/svg/leaguegothic.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: +50 bounty.  I am having the same problem and can't find any leads on how to solve it. you can see the problem here: [http://www.fease.org/code](http://www.fease.org/code/ "here").  Perfect in mac browsers, as well as PC IE and FF, flawed in windows Chrome. any help is appreciated

Comment: @Sebastian: btw, if you click Retag instead of Edit, you can change tags without going through the whole edit approval process.

Comment: duh, i don't know how i missed that, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is highly likely that the webfont is not assembled properly.

I have downloaded CaviarDreams font which is used on Sebastian's site and got the same bug.

Then I downloaded it from here: http://www.dafont.com/caviar-dreams.font, used [fontsquirrel.com's typekit generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), and the result was perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 I have a feeling that you are right. Will try this tonight, if it gets it done the bounty's yours :)

Comment: worked, like a charm, thank you. i'll award the bounty as soon as SO lets me (16hs). also, i'd love to see the site you're using it for, its a cool but problematic font choice.

Comment: OP here -- gonna try this out tonight and see where it gets me.  Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: I was having the same issue on IE7 and on some computers with IE8.  Just went back to regenerate at Font Squirrel and saw that there is a Fix Glyphs section in the advanced settings with checkboxes for spaces and hyphens.

Comment: Nice spot, Dylan.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding them using fontsquirrel.com Typekit generator I am not sure what the problem is, but it might help.

Comment: +1 for being firsts, giving the bounty for unclenorton for giving me the pinpoint solution tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from a previous StackFlow question. Refer to the htaccess part, not the beginning:

[font-face with wrong MIME type in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-problem-in-chrome)

Also refer to this ticket with Google:

[http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72727&q=%40font-face&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72727&q=@font-face&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS)

Last resort: re-generate your font with [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Comment: Well, it seems to be somehow connected with problem, but what's the solution in this case? Chrome rejects both 'application/x-font-woff' and 'application/x-woff' for .woff fonts. Curiously, reassembling the font fixes the bug but doesn't get rid of the warning.

Comment: I think Google still considers this an open bug. So as of now there is no official solution. Workarounds for the warning I haven't found yet...

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, giving the bounty for unclenorton for giving me the pinpoint solution

Answer (score 0):

I commented on this question before and just found some extra information for people having trouble with the boxes and spaces with 'X' for line breaks, end of line and space characters in Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox.  Yes, sometimes regenerating the font files improves things but then I noticed my problems largely went away when I added unicode characters for spaces and new lines.  Paste the following into the Unicode Ranges field on FontSquirrel when generating your fonts:

```
0085, 000A, 000B, 000C, 000D, 2028, 2029
```

For good measure I also type a spacebar into the Single Characters field.