# Twitter-bootstrap header tags are garbled in safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would html text sometimes appear garbled when viewing on Chrome or Safari on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327525/why-would-html-text-sometimes-appear-garbled-when-viewing-on-chrome-or-safari-on)

I tested my pages in browsers for awhile as I've been designing. and I've noticed the header tags `<h1>` through `<h6>` are not being rendered correctly in safari...like there's a missing font. I'm running twitter-bootstrap and for some reason I cannot fix this problem.

[image]

I honestly think its my computer fonts and not the browser.

If I disable `optimizelegibility` in CSS it works fine in Safari, however, every other computer I've tried it on works just fine.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #222222;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility; /*Causing problems */
}
```

I don't even have helvetica Neue on my windows computer, I have all the Neue LT fonts, however.

**UPDATE**

Okay I used font frenzy and revert my fonts back to windows installed phones. I never had Helvetica Neue only Helvetica Neue LT.

I got it to display normal, but this raises a good question. Are people with these fonts install going to have the same issue as me?

Should I attempt to use fontface to fix this? How honestly could I make this so no everyone would have the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Is this essentially the same question? [Why would html text sometimes appear garbled when viewing on Chrome or Safari on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327525/why-would-html-text-sometimes-appear-garbled-when-viewing-on-chrome-or-safari-on)

And the answer (from link):

Easily recreated by using an older version of Windows as well as an older branch of Chrome. Seems like Chrome 4-8 have this issue. For testing purposes, boot into XP with Chrome 4. The problem lies in `text-rendering: optimizelegibility`. This is a reported bug in older Chrome versions when using optimizelegibility with `@font-face` when using woff fonts. If you can reproduce the issue, try taking out `vertical-align: baseline` and see if the rendering is still garbled.

---

This link here also has an interesting comment thread on the issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39017

Comment: baseline is only applied to classes that are not used at all. Why would the same version browsers on two separate computers produce different results?

Comment: Are both computers running the same operating systems, and the same versions? This could play a prominent role.

If `"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` defaults to `Helvetica Neue LT` (Linotype), and this causes you to constantly run into the problem across your LT-user userbase, perhaps you could sacrifice `optimizeLegibility`? I'd rather have my users looking at standard rendering/Arial than what I see above. I shall keep searching for a solution for the Linotypers!

Comment: I do not disagree. But is there a way to make it default to arial not any brand of Helvetica Neue? Yes, most of the computers are running the same version, however, I'm running an apache server on linux on my labtop.