# Webfont character missing in Chrome 17

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I have a font that I've modified to add some European characters. I've generated a pack using Fontsquirrel and it works fine in all browsers. But I got the surprise once I checked the site at work, where the version 17.0.963.79 m of Chrome doesn't recognize the "space" character!

The character is in the character map since Chrome (at home!) FF, and EVEN IE recognizes it...

Any clue?

The CSS snippet Fontsquirrel generated for me is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BallparkWeiner';
    src: url('ballparkweiner-webfont.eot');
    src: url('ballparkweiner-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('ballparkweiner-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('ballparkweiner-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ballparkweiner-webfont.svg#BallparkWeiner') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

just in case there's some fix needed for any versions of Chrome

And here is an example of how it is rendering the error in Chrome and FF

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315788/chrome-10-windows-font-face-encoding-trouble