# Font-Face Not loaded

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm using some costume Fonts in my web site but i got probleme with one it's not loaded and i can't figure out the probleme, here's the code :

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: OuachitaWayWbw; 
    src: url('fonts/Ouachita Way Wbw.ttf') format("truetype") ; 
    font-family: 'ChromeYellowNF'; 
    src: url('fonts/Chrome Yellow NF.ttf');
}

#name { 
    font-size:26px; 
    font-family: 'OuachitaWayWbw'; 
    padding-top:30px; 
    color:#000000; 
    margin-bottom:20px; 
}
```

The `ChromeYellowNF` work's. also i have tried to put each one in diffirent `Font-face` but did't worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to have an @font-face declaration for each font:

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: OuachitaWayWbw; 
  src: url('fonts/Ouachita Way Wbw.ttf') format("truetype") ; 
}
@font-face { 
  font-family: ChromeYellowNF; 
  src: url('fonts/Chrome Yellow NF.ttf');
}
```

The single quotes are not required.

If you are wanting to use custom fonts for IE9 you will need to also provide an ".eot" font file. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

EDIT: Ok, different browsers have different ways of implementing fonts:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: OuachitaWayWbw; 
   src: url('fonts/Ouachita Way Wbw.ttf') format("truetype"),
        url('fonts/Ouachita Way Wbw.woff') format("woff");
   src: url('fonts/Ouachita Way Wbw.eot');
}
```

You may also need to add the following types to an .htaccess/IIS:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

Taken from here: [font-face with wrong MIME type in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-problem-in-chrome)

Comment: I have made some test and look what's i got : `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream`

Comment: I have edited my post above - I think you need the correct font format for the browser you are using and also need to the types to an .htaccess or to the MIME types in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this but it looks like your font-family name should probably be in quotes. Also you might try putting each font in there own @font-face declaration. That should solve your problem. I think it is taking the last font-family specified within the @font-face declaration.

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'OuachitaWayWbw'; 
  src: url('fonts/Ouachita Way Wbw.ttf') format("truetype") ; 
}
@font-face { 
  font-family: 'ChromeYellowNF'; 
  src: url('fonts/Chrome Yellow NF.ttf');
}

#name {
    font-size:26px; 
    font-family: 'OuachitaWayWbw'; 
    padding-top:30px; 
    color:#000000; 
    margin-bottom:20px; 
}
```

Comment: I have already done this but with no result. and for the quotes because i have made lot of change so i forgot the rewrite them.

Comment: I have made some test and look what's i got : `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream`