# web-fonts rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have a problem with font rendering in Firefox and Chrome on Windows systems.
Here is the font face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Museo500';
    src: url('../fonts/museo500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.eot');
    src: local('?'), 
    url('../fonts/museo500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/museo500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('../fonts/museo500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.svg#webfontr3rD8cn7') format('svg');
}
```

and here is a input class:

```
input {
    font-family: Museo500, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #ff0000;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I cannot understand how on IE8 the font is rendered well and on Firefox and Chrome the font is not render correctly. If someone can give me a suggestion I'll be grateful.
Or maybe a font that replaces museo500, museo700.
Thank you.

Comment: About @97ldave answer - you can access font files via their url and make sure it's extension problem.

Comment: @Kamo is not an url problem, I fixed in chrom by moving last svg line up and now is working just fine on webkit browers , I must see how to fix that on firefox

Comment: I think there is a bug in Firefox where don't files have to be in the same folder as the CSS file. I had this problem before but not sure if Firefox have fixed it.

Comment: That's meant to say "Font" files, not "don't" files

Comment: Yeah, @font-face has some problematic issues - I also had a lot of problems implementing multiple fonts with this rule. I can suggest you http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate to render custom fonts, maybe you'd want to give it a try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question here: [Font-Face Not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894)

You may need to add the types via .htaccess or MIME types to IIS.

Comment: the font is loaded because I have two buttons: 1 is <a> tag where font is rendered well and other button <input type="submit"> where the font is not rendered well :(

Comment: Is more a problem regarding OS and browser-side ... because for example on windows 7 is not working on nothing chrome, ie,ff,safari ...