# @font-face not loading font

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to use @font-face and for some reason it is failing to work (IE9, Chrome  and Firefox). I have made sure that I am pointing to the correct directory when loading the font however it still doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'test';
src: url('../fonts/FontName.ttf'),
         url('../fonts/FontName.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And calling it:

```
#header{
text-align:left;
padding: 10px;
font-family:test;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: I would use a tool like Fiddler2, the F12 Developer Tools (IE), or the  Developer Tools in Chrome to look for 404 responses trying to load the font files. Perhaps the path isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Error: Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "file:///C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Website/fonts/Minecraft.ttf".

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894

Comment: There is little hope getting solutions without some tangible information, such as the URL of the page, so that the problem can be observed and studied. Information about the origin of the font can be essential, too. (It is not uncommon to see broken fonts distributed on the web.)

Comment: One thing to note is that a font won't be downloaded until it is actually used.  So if you add a new font URl directive, you should also try to use it via CSS or style rules to cause the font to be downloaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Internet Explorer uses the version .woff of the font, which is not used by you in the code, instead of using the version .eot. I used the [@font-face generato](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)r tool from [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to get all the different font variations

The output should look something like this:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'test';
src: url('../fonts/FontName.eot'),
     url('../fonts/FontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/FontName.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/FontName.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in addition to what people have been saying about the different types of fonts (and using the `format()` element along with `url()`), it would also be worthwhile to check your css inhertiance to make sure that nothing is setting `#header` or the elements inside of it to `font-weight: bold`.  Since you only specify a normal weight/normal style font, if something makes it bold, the font won't show up.

Answer (score 2):

Run your fonts through the FontSquirrel generator and it will convert them to the various formats supported by different browsers.

It should also give you a blob of CSS that you can use, just adjust the paths to the font files.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: ok, I've done this, and I've put them in my fonts folder, copied the css (edited it to look in font folder) and it seems to work perfectly in the example, yet on my actual page, i get "Failed to load resource"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'test';
src: url('../fonts/Minecraft.ttf'),
         url('../fonts/minecraft.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

In your code you have two folder: fonts and font, in my example I have used fonts

Comment: oh, the font folder, i changed that in my real code, it doesn't change

Comment: Return some error? if you have the folder fonts into another folder I don't know

Comment: Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "file:///C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Website/fonts/Minecraft.ttf".

Answer (score -6):

Easy game. When loading it, you should out the name between '  ':

font-family: 'test';

This will surely work.