# @font-face is not working as it should

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

So I use some really neat typefaces, and I have never had any problem with @font-face before, however, these just doesn't seem to work. :(
Any ideas what went wrong?

Path to CSS: http://carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/css/style.css

Path to Fontsfolder: http://carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/css/fonts

```
@font-face {
font-family: silverfake;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/silverfake.otf');
}

@font-face {
font-family: molesk;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/molesk.otf');
}

@font-face {
font-family: ballpark;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/ballpark.TTF') format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: you can upload your font kit here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and after download you can just copy paste their css from the download folder

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894 Could be a few different reasons.

Comment: Font folder missing: “The requested URL /friday-quiz/css/fonts was not found on this server.”

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't link to the fonts correctly. 
It's usually something small like;

```
src: url('../fonts/silverfake.otf');
```

instead of

```
src: url('fonts/silverfake.otf');
```

Try using [fontsquirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to make sure everything is linked correctly, and is browser friendly.

Comment: Not in his case I think, see his links.

Comment: the links require me to login. couldn't check them out.

Comment: Me neither, but you can see that his fonts folder is inside the css folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found at least an answer to getting Molesk working:

```
@font-face {
font-family:"molesk";
src:url("molesk.eot?") 
format("eot"),url("molesk.woff") 
format("woff"),url("molesk.ttf") 
format("truetype"),url("molesk.svg#molesk") 
format("svg");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;}
```