# @font-face doesn't work in ff/opera just in chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, opentype

well, I have problem with font-face element. It works very well in chrome, but isn't work in any browser. What is the problem? Thanks in advance.

demo -> http://codepen.io/designhorf/pen/AlJKp

Comment: try to generate some snippets on [fontsquirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), compare and figure it out

Comment: this url http://www.designhorf.com/font/Nexa_Bold.otf, is not working.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894

Answer (score 1):

You need more than just an otf file. Different browsers want different file types, and IE as usual doesn't behave.

`@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'YourFont';
    src: url('../fonts/YourFont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/YourFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/YourFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/YourFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/YourFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`

A great resource for generating both the code and and the files is 
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Have fun!

Comment: if you're targeting IE9 and up, having just .otf and .woff is actually enough. No neeed for a ttf, eot and svg (svg and eot are, in fact, highly discouraged. The first is only for IE8 and below, the latter is  huge and renders pretty horridly). Loading it in [otf, woff] order will work in FF, Chrome, Opera, IE9+, and Android 4.4+, as well as FF/Chrome on Android 4.*