# StobiSans is diffrent in Mozilla using font-face

Tags: html, fonts, font-face, mozilla

I'm using embedded fonts using font-face

```
   @font-face {
            font-family: StobiSans Regular;
            src: url('../STOBISANS-REGULAR.OTF');
        }
```

In other browsers text looks ok, however in mozilla text is like bold. Does somebody knows what is the problem?

Comment: Is that all your CSS? Take a look here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894

Comment: That's all in my css

Comment: Take a look at the link I put in my previous comment to see if that helps.

Comment: Can you add a link to `STOBISANS-REGULAR.OTF`? So we can test.