# Correct Apache AddType directives for font MIME types

Tags: apache, fonts, mime, woff, eot

I’m using @font-face for embedded fonts (thanks [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax)). In trying to fix Chrome’s warning about wrong MIME type for woff fonts, I’ve discovered a mass of conflicting suggestions.

Everyone seems to agree that .eot fonts (for IE 6-8?) should be served using

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
```

For .ttf fonts (older non-IE browsers?) I’ve seen

```
AddType application/x-font-ttf        .ttf
AddType application/octet-stream      .ttf
AddType font/truetype                 .ttf
AddType font/ttf                      .ttf
```

And for .woff fonts (the new standard?) I’ve seen

```
AddType application/font-wof          .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff       .woff
AddType application/x-woff            .woff
```

I understand the [correct MIME type](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/) for woff will be application/font-woff, but until the standard is official, [application/x-font-woff is understood by Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70283#hc3).

I realise I’ve half answered my question in asking it, but the question is really: is there any authoritative guidance or further advice about what MIME types should be used for fonts?

Update (in case it’s of any help to anyone else): since there seems to be nothing authoritative, I’ve settled on using the following font MIME types in my .htaccess (which at least keeps Chrome happy):

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf        .ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff       .woff
```

Comment: +1 I'm trying to put this in a framework so eventhough browsers can cope with `application/octet-stream`, I'd like to do this the 'right' way to ensure interoperability (e.g. allow users to enable gzip for certain content types)

Comment: Thanks for updating with what worked for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, MIME types come from RFC.
You have a exhaustive list on the [IANA site](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) but none refers to the font extensions.
Moreover, [document describing WOFF format](http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-2009-09-16.html) is draft and does not refer to the mime type to use.
No reliable reference on the subject seems to exist for now.

#### Update

The W3C has now released WOFF as a recommendation, and in [Appendix B](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b) defined the MIME type as `application/font-woff`. It's also been added to the [IANA site](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) that you mentioned now. *-GKFX*

Comment: Hint: `application/font-woff` mime is now deprecated. Use `font/woff` instead. See [IANA site](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Answer (score 77):

I realize that this question is old, but for anyone looking for a quick copy/paste for adding font MIME types to their .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
    AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
    AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
    AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
    AddType application/font-woff            .woff
    AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Chris Clower [here the link to my question help this to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634607/font-face-showing-404-error-for-fonts-i-imported-woff-and-ttf)

Comment: @VivekVikranth it should be able to be safely pasted anywhere in the .htaccess file, just be sure NOT to paste it inside of a set of tags, for example `<IfModule>`. Putting it on either the first line or last line of the file would work.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that Apache's mime.types file lists all of these. A good way to check is to look at the server reponse header and see if has a content-type.

Comment: @ChrisClower, why shouldn't this go inside tags? Should I also move out other lines such as those for css, html, jpg, and so on?

Answer (score 7):

I just did some research on [IANA official list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types). This appears to be the current state of the play as at May 2013:

These three are official and assigned by IANA:

- svg  as "image/svg+xml"
- woff as "application/font-woff"
- eot  as "application/vnd.ms-fontobject"

These are not not official/assigned, and so must use the 'x-' syntax:

- ttf  as "application/x-font-ttf"
- otf  as "application/x-font-opentype"

It appears that the 'font' type does not exist, so any time type you see 'font/xxx' it is bogus. Possibly 'x-font/xxx' would be allowable, not sure. IIS8 ships with a couple entries like this. Not sure if MS thinks these 'font/xxx' ones are needed for compatibility, or if they just don't read RFCs :-)

The application/font-woff appears new and maybe only official since Jan 2013. So "application/x-font-woff" might be safer/more compatible in the short term.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's worth mentioning that, as from March 2013, [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) gave the `.otf` and `.ttf` extentions the MIME type of [application/font-sfnt](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/font-sfnt).

For a complete and current list of official MIME types, see my answer on [Proper MIME type for fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts/20723357/#answer-20723357)

Comment: Duplicate posts are auto-detected on SO, and you risk having *both* posts deleted.

Answer (score 3):

in 2019 you can use:

```
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/woff .woff
AddType font/woff2 .woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a example for caching all font types in apache (tested on Google Page Speed):

```
AddType application/font-sfnt            otf ttf
AddType application/font-woff            woff
AddType application/font-woff2           woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    eot


ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-sfnt "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
```

Comment: Instead of `application/font-woff`  you can just use the simpler `font/woff`