# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3

Tags: font-face, font-awesome

I'm getting this error message whenever I load my application page.
I'm using Apache. Following is my css code.

> url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff')

Firefox throws

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found url.../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3

While chrome says

> GET url.../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3 404 (Not Found)

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: we would have to know your directory structure. Where is the parent file loading the .woff file? 404 simply means the file your are are pointing to doens't exist or "file not found"

Comment: The font is in same folder as the others font (.ttf, .svg) and they are working fine. And css link is also same as the other fonts.

url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');

Comment: in that case, could there be a typo in the url? a capital letter there there should not bet, etc?

Comment: I double checked the URL, there is nothing wrong in it.
Here is my directory structure.
`approot(assets/fonts/fontfiles, assets/css/cssfiles)`
I'm using relative URL in css files to point to the fonts files.

Comment: Also on localhost, it works fine but on live it is throwing this 404  error.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This worked for me:
Add the following lines to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
   <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

You have to add these lines because by default Apache is not configured with .woff as a default MIME-type. [Apache default MIME-type](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#defaulttype)
This holds for IIS as well. As Seb Duggan explains here:[IIS default MIME](http://sebduggan.com/blog/serving-web-fonts-from-iis/), by default .woff files will not be served by the server.

Comment: What I should be doing for tomcat?

Answer (score 17):

I've updated mime-types in my IIS web server and that resolves my problem.

```
Extention > .ttf    MimeType > application/x-font-ttf
Extention > .woff   MimeType > application/x-font-woff
Extention > .woff2  MimeType > application/x-font-woff2
```

I don't need to change anything in web.config. However, IIS will eventually updates web.config.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I solve it also using adding the file type under handlers on your web.config for any application .net, angular etc you can set a web.config on IIS

```
     <handlers>
     <add name="fonts" path="*.woff" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="fonts2" path="*.woff2" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     </handlers>
```

Comment: Configuration -> SystemWebServer -> Handlers

Answer (score 6):

Add "src:" before url, example:-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');    
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype');    
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2');    
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff');    
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype');    
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution with teak worked for us. We have website under a folder. “https://myweb.com/mysite”. The error we are getting “GET https://myweb.com/mysite/Areas/Mechanical/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)”. We add the “mysite” folder to font-awesome.min.css fontface as “src: url('../mysite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');“

Comment: This method works, when using your regular Webhosting on Apache.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the accepted answer did not work for me, But I copied the following configuration to make it work :

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00"/>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use IIS 6, you can solve your problem by adding Mime to IIS:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have access to your webserver config, you can also just RENAME the file so that it ends in svg (but retain the format). Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions above works for you try this solution specified is one of the stackoverflow pages that to set false to BundleTable.EnableOptimizations in BundleConfig.cs file in the App_Start folder.

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

However, you will lose the benefits of the bundling which reduces the number of http request from your browser.