# Academicons and HTML not showing correctly

Tags: html, icons

This question was already asked before, nevertheless the solution that was suggested didn't solved the problem.

I am trying to include the ResearchGate academicon in my website, nevertheless it is displayed as a square in Google Chrome and as square with numbers inside in Firefox, while loading the website from the server.

If I download all the files to my computer (as a zip and then opening directly the html file) it displays correctly.

The previous question that was asked with the exactly same problem (and overall situation, it actually uses the same template for the website as I do) is here with its discussion is here [Font-awesome: An emoticon looks different on my computer than on the actual webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290216/font-awesome-an-emoticon-looks-different-on-my-computer-than-on-the-actual-webp)

I already tried doing the suggested modifications in the .htaccess file without success. Does anyone of you have an idea on how to attack this problem?

Many thanks!

---

Edit 1:
I include here the mime types reported by my CPanel:
[Mime Types in CPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7yZw.png)

Edit 2:

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post the pictures, but they are identical to the quoted previous Question (linked: Font-awesone: An emoticon looks...).

Comment: If the mime type is the problem, you need to provide a few informations about your server setup (apache, nginx, something else?) But I would suggest to debug this problems via browser developer tools. Does the font get applied? with which mime type it is loaded?

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. The server has cpanel and I think it is running in Apache. The reason is because it has an "Advanced Option" that says "Apache Handlers". The mime types I added through the .htaccess file, and they are recognized. If I go to the mime types they appear correctly with the extensions eot woff otf ttf

Answer (score 0):

Is it even in the correct size (maybe it is very small)? When not: Check font-awesome.com .. it has set some classes with allows you to size your icons. Try this class on your html in the `<i>` tag: fa-x3

I´ve made the same on [this page](http://mike-kaufmann.de/other/kirakos/index.html) in the footer.

Don't kill me if I am totally wrong for what you are searching.

Comment: Hello, I may have not been clear enough about the problem. I updated the question to make explicit the problem. Thanks!