# CSS see fonts on MacOS can't see fonts on VPS (Ubuntu 20.04 LST)

Tags: css, macos, ubuntu, fonts, vps

**Problem**: CSS can detect the fonts when using macOS when I download Google fonts. CSS cannot see the fonts using the same code on VPS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. If I use  @import to get the link to the fonts from Google, then CSS can see the fonts in both cases (i.e., both on macOS and VPS Ubuntu). I do not want to use a link; I want to have the fonts on my VPS hard drive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My HTML Test</title>

    <style>
        /*
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Updock&display=swap');
        */
        
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Updock';
            src: url('/Updock/Updock-Regular.ttf');
        }
        
        .myFont {
            font-family: 'Updock';
            
        }

        .defaultFont {
            font-family: cursive;
        }
    
        .myFirstLetter::first-letter {
            font-size: 200%;
            color:red
        }
        
    
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="myFont">
        <h1>This Is My Font!!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class = "defaultFont, myFirstLetter">
        

        <h1>This Is Default Font!</h1>
    </div>
    
   
</body>
</html>
```

The directory path for the font files is correct. I used the same directory name and path on VPS, which was successful on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try put this on your VPS machine, inside .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-font-ttf       .ttf
</IfModule>
```

Be sure you have installed mod_mime module.
Also, check this answer:
[Correct Apache AddType directives for font MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415640/correct-apache-addtype-directives-for-font-mime-types)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy to node.js. Do you have the similar version of the code for NGINX config file instead?