# Why the 404 error in my ttf font?

Tags: http-status-code-404, font-face, sass

On my site, I use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

I have the following code:

**--- Edit ---**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BauhausBold';
    src: url('/Type/bauhaus_bold.eot');
    src: url('/Type/bauhaus_bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Type/bauhaus_bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Type/bauhaus_bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/Type/bauhaus_bold.svg#BauhausBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

To use this font:

```
font-family: quote('bind'), arial;
```

But we always get the error 404 on my site. See the image:

[image: Error 404]

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAhWY.png

You can access the site: [bindsolution.com](http://bindsolution.com) if they wish.

**Thank you all for your help!**

Comment: where did you get quote('bind') from?

Comment: See this:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#string_functions

Comment: have you tried to include your fonts also in .woff and .svg? Furthermore are the paths to your fonts relative to your domain?

Comment: Add multiple formats, see the issue edited.

Comment: i would try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts

Answer (score 1):

I've just had exactly same problem and I couldn't solve it. I thought it was due to relative path but it wasn't. It turned out that I had my fonts names in CSS in uppercase while the files' names were actualy lower case. Previous server didn't care but this one does. That is all.