# Windows Azure CDN and *.woff fonts

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I use CDN for my cloud services in Azure, but fonts (*.woff) does not work!

When i use just iis for static files i solve this problem like

```
<staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts)

But how i can do it in microsoft azure cdn?

Comment: Are you using the CDN with Blob Storage?

Comment: No. With cloud service (http://mysite.cloudapp.net/cdn/)

Comment: Could you post the response headers you're getting in Fiddler when requesting the URL from the CDN. The CDN should reuse most of the headers you define on your file. And if you defined the mimeType in the web.config, you should also get that mimeType when calling the url from the CDN.

Comment: Fiddler show correct mime-type RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
application/x-font-woff: 23 168
              ~headers~: 300

Comment: Maybe it's because of the cross domain request?

Comment: And in Internet Explorer. Chrome, Opera - ok.

Answer (score 1):

Its cross-domain so you also need to add:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="HEAD,GET,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```