# Custom Font not working on Safari or Firefox

Tags: css, fonts

I am working on animated WebBanners in Adobe Animate. Most of the text created as Static text. But there is one block of variable copy that's created as Dynamic Text. This shows up fine in Chrome but not in Safari or Firefox.
I am new to coding. Have linked my CSS of font style that has @font face for my custom fonts.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944595/14795263

A link to the solution from an earlier poster, Carol, above. Yay Hivemind!

Apparently you might need to specify both [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) AND domainname.com in font.com's domain configuration. Chrome and Safari are sensitive to this, and it might help for Firefox as well.

Comment: it's fixed now. I am not sure of the above. What I needed to do was to code the whole path to the googleapis. I was just linking my CSS file to my HTML code but wasn't coding the path. That's how rookie I am. :) Thanks for replying so fast.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. :)