# how to put fontawesome inside cache using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, font-awesome, cache-control, deflate

I use google speed for optimizing my website, and it tell me to put in cache font awesome.

I have the following code  for my htaccess but it does not seems to put in cache that file :

```
# MOD_DEFLATE COMPRESSION
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
#Pour les navigateurs incompatibles
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
#ne pas mettre en cache si ces fichiers le sont déjà
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
#les proxies doivent donner le bon contenu
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
 AddType image/x-icon .ico
 ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript A259200
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
# Add a far future Expires header for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|gz|ttf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
 </FilesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
</filesMatch>
# Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# KILL THEM ETAGS
Header unset ETag
FileETag none
```

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually have the fontawesome fonts on your server you can cache them in the .htaccess file like so;

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  Header set cache-control: public
  ExpiresActive on

  ExpiresByType font/ttf      "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/woff     "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same method to cache font awesome or any other font files in the same way that you would cache the more common files. This question should answer your question [Setting expire headers for fonts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429540/setting-expire-headers-for-fonts-not-working)

```
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
```

To give a further improvement, you can also compress the font. This article goes into a lot of detail on how to perform this https://zoompf.com/blog/2014/08/bootstrap-fonts In short the following code should do what you need.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
```