# Grails / Chrome Error: resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: google-chrome, grails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

How in Chrome can you set the mime type for a woff font, as used by the font-awesome bootstrap library?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Grails custom mapper](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/6.%20Creating%20custom%20mappers.html) by putting the below `FontResourceMapper.groovy` file into the folder: `grails-app/resourceMappers/`

**FontResourceMapper.groovy**

```
import org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.MapperPhase

class FontResourceMapper {

   static phase = MapperPhase.ALTERNATEREPRESENTATION
   static defaultIncludes = ["**/*.woff"]

   def map(resource, config) {
      // Changes "application/octet-stream" to correct MIME type to avoid browser warning
      resource.requestProcessors << { req, resp ->
         resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/font-woff")
         }
      }

}
```

Adapted from [halfbaked's solution](https://github.com/halfbaked/grails-font-awesome-resources/blob/master/grails-app/resourceMappers/FontAwesomePluginResourceMapper.groovy).

Comment: Any ideas why this needs to be done and why declaring a custom mapping in Config.droovy's grails.mime.types (as per my answer below) doesn't work?

Comment: @Spider, I don't know, but it sure would be cleaner if the `Config.groovy` solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

**In Config.groovy:**

```
grails.mime.types = [
    all:           '*/*',
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    ...
    woff:          'font/opentype'
]
```

Comment: It seems the type for `woff` should be `application/font-woff`, but it's still not working for us (Grails 2.2.3).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142316/1553812