# Import html fonts and their style variations?

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser

I'm implementing  google's font named `Roboto` in my site.

I need 2 types : `bold` and `regular`.

[image]

So I checked both types and pressed the download button :

[image]

But in the downloaded rar file I got ALL the font styles ( also ones which I didn't choose) :

[image]

Anyway I wanted to test the **regular** font  : (*the fonts are now in my site and not being loaded from google*).

*(I got those other extensions types (eot,woff,svg) using a font converter (http://www.font2web.com/))*

So I did :

```
 <style type="text/css">

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-Regularo.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }


   body  { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }

    </style>
```

**Question :**

Let's say I want to apply a `Roboto bold` style to a `div`.

Should I do it like this :

```
 div  { 
       font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
       font-weight:bold
      }
```

or should I do this ( start all over...)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-bold';
    src: url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    ...
    }
```

and then

```
 div  { font-family: 'Roboto-bold', sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: /* links to the Regular files */;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: /* links to the Bold files */;
}
```

Notice how the same font name is used in both `@font-face` rules. Now the browser knows that the font "Roboto" exists in two variants. The browser will automatically choose the best variant based on your CSS. So, for example:

```
div {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here the browser chooses the Bold font file. It's all automatic. You just have to make sure that you set up the `@font-face` rules correctly.

Comment: Why not just bold the regular font, instead of downloading and using the Roboto-bold fonts? Won't they look the same? They look pretty much identical to my eye, when testing in the browser.

Comment: Nm, I discovered this, and was reminded of the point: http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

Answer (score 4):

Any reason why you're downloading the font? If you're using it in a web site you can just use the `@import` code given by Google.

The checkboxes choosing the variations at the beginning only define the import code. If you choose to download the font to your computer it always gives you all variations regardless of the choices you made.

To use the font just include the link to the stylesheet containing the `@font-face` which google gives you. E.g.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

or

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
```

in your existing stylesheet.

And then it's just a case of setting the font-family for the elements you choose. E.g.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

**Regarding your question  :**

Yes, you need a separate @font-face for each variation. See example from google

Google example :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v8/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v8/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

If you don't include a bold variation for your font the browser will render bolded text as faux-bold instead. This can have variable appearance depending on browser and OS. Likewise for italic and bold-italic.

Comment: yes there is. google has a problem with mime types compatibility which shows a warning. I had to download the font and register the current mime types.

Comment: and BTW  - your answer doesnt related to my question but to the way i donload fonts.

Comment: It seems there should no longer be an issue regarding MIME types for google fonts on chrome: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594823/mime-type-for-woff-fonts

Comment: well there is because the after changing my iis  mime types settings - after getting this error/warning `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream` - it has been solved.

Comment: In addition, warnings in the console regarding MIME types for fonts are usually safe to ignore

Comment: when im dealing with ie9 which doesnt work , and i see warnings in chrome , i tend to solve that problem with chrome first , and later deal with IE.

Comment: Harry you comment to yotam was all i needed ( and not whether i download or not the fonts)....:-)

Comment: I'm glad it helped but I'm still unsure how serving the font locally rather than from Google's servers solves your MIME type issues.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it looks like your only declaring one `font-face` rule, related to the Regular version of the Roboto font.

Using the CSS from your question:

```
div {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Will result in the browser *faux* bolding the font. The reason is, the font-face rule hasn't been included for the **bold** version of the font. Reference here: http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

As others (@yotam, etc) have mentioned (regardless of how the fonts are being served) you would need to declare a font-face rule for each font weight.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: /* links to the Regular files */;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: /* links to the Bold files */;
}
```

You would then use that font weight as follows:

```
body {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

I would stress to use the actual font weight value and not `font-weight: bold`. As mentioned using `font-weight: bold` leaves the decision down the the browser.

At some point you may use a font with weights of `700, 900`. Say `700` is be bold, `900` extra bold. If your declaring `font-weight: bold` the `900` weight would be used, which isn't the effect you would want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start all over.. if you got `@font-face` in your style then all you need to add is font-family like you said.

```
div  { 
       font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
       font-weight:bold
      }
```

And just for make it clear you can make the font as default by using him in body element like this

```
body  { 
       font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
       font-weight:bold
      }
```

EDIT:

You might considering download your font into your website folder, then instead taking website loading time you'll just have to add the next code to your `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('fonts/font.ttf'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    /*....*/
    }
```

The font should be inside fonts folder and he named font.

Comment: If I use your first code , Must i also download the Roboto-bold font ? I mean - how will the browser know how to render a bolded font if he doesnt has it... ?

Comment: You using src (Source) from a website, if you got source already you don't have to download the font since you already have him in your website. You can download the font and use him as local and save a load time

Comment: Yotam that wasn't my question. I'll rephrase. If I use only `Roboto-Regular` and then do `font-weight:bold` , will the browser know how to render the bold font even if i didnt do : `url('/font-face/Regular/Roboto-bold(!!!!).ttf')` ?

Comment: Yotam what makes you think i didnt download the fonts ? I explicitly said (_downloaded rar file _). the fonts are in my solution.  my question still remains about whether or not should i use SRC to the bolded version.

Comment: It the same, if you use src or local host. But since you have the fonts in local host you should be using them, it saving you loading bettwen the websites. The quailty bettwen SRC and LocalHost will be the same if the font are same.

Comment: Yes, you need a separate `@font-face` for each variation. See example from google: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700

Comment: @yotam Does downloading **only** the regular font (not bold) and then do `font-weight:bold` is exactly the same as if i downloaded the pure bolded font version ?

Comment: Ofcourse, it will allways be the same unless you change something in the font file.

Comment: @yotam If I can do `font-weight:bold` , why would I ever want to  use `Robto-download.ttf` ???

Comment: I don't know, maybe because the new font?