# CSS How to embed several Font-Weights at once

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I was using the `Open Sans Font-Family` from the Google Fonts Library, where you can just use this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And it will export all the fonts at once and when you are using Open Sans as Font-Family you can simply put font-weight: XXX and it will automatically use the right font for it.

I downloaded the files directly because we have to use them local now, but it gives me like 10 different fonts for each style and weight (normal, medium, bold, bold italic e.g). I don't want to import them separately and use font-family: Open-Sans-Bold (for example)

Is there any way to import them all at once or tell CSS that it's basically the same Font-Family just a different weight?

Comment: I think you should see this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166060/import-html-fonts-and-their-style-variations

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed font css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737168/how-to-embed-font-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Please excuse my example of Comic Sans neue, just something I had laying about)

---

You have to add them all separate, look at the following code. Each one has a different 'font-weight' and has a new font file (`light`, `regular` and `bold`).

Each font file has a different font-size which means that if you want to add all of them, you'll have to add them all this way (for each one you want).

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comic Neue';
  src: url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Light.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Light.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comic Neue';
  src: url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comic Neue';
  src: url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/ComicNeue-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Calling it is simple after, in your CSS:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300; /*or 100/700*/
}
```

Obviously, you'd replace this with `Open Sans` and the `Open Sans` font files.

Comment: Thanks, this did the Job and the Comic Sans made my day :>

Comment: Haha, all I had laying about! Glad I could help though! @PhilipFeldmann

Comment: Great answer. I see this done incorrectly so often. Now if I see someone do this incorrectly I will point them to this answer. 